# Is there a `valueof` similar to `keyof` in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

I want to be able to assign an object property to a value given a key and value as inputs yet still be able to determine the type of the value. It's a bit hard to explain so this code should reveal the problem:

```
type JWT = { id: string, token: string, expire: Date };
const obj: JWT = { id: 'abc123', token: 'tk01', expire: new Date(2018, 2, 14) };

function print(key: keyof JWT) {
    switch (key) {
        case 'id':
        case 'token':
            console.log(obj[key].toUpperCase());
            break;
        case 'expire':
            console.log(obj[key].toISOString());
            break;
    }
}

function onChange(key: keyof JWT, value: any) {
    switch (key) {
        case 'id':
        case 'token':
            obj[key] = value + ' (assigned)';
            break;
        case 'expire':
            obj[key] = value;
            break;
    }
}

print('id');
print('expire');
onChange('id', 'def456');
onChange('expire', new Date(2018, 3, 14));
print('id');
print('expire');

onChange('expire', 1337); // should fail here at compile time
print('expire'); // actually fails here at run time
```

I tried changing `value: any` to `value: valueof JWT` but that didn't work.

Ideally, `onChange('expire', 1337)` would fail because `1337` is not a Date type.

How can I change `value: any` to be the value of the given key?

Comment: The package type-fest (https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest) has the type ValueOf, as well as many other exceedingly useful utility types - I use it all the time, and would highly recommend it.

Answer (score 770, accepted):

UPDATE: Looks like the question title attracts people looking for a union of all possible property value types, analogous to the way `keyof` gives you the union of all possible property key types.  Let's help those people first.  You can make a `ValueOf` analogous to `keyof`, by using [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `keyof T` as the key, like so:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
```

which gives you

```
type Foo = { a: string, b: number };
type ValueOfFoo = ValueOf<Foo>; // string | number
```

---

For the question as stated, you can use individual keys, narrower than `keyof T`, to extract just the value type you care about:

```
type sameAsString = Foo['a']; // look up a in Foo
type sameAsNumber = Foo['b']; // look up b in Foo
```

In order to make sure that the key/value pair "match up" properly in a function, you should use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) as well as indexed access types, like this:

```
declare function onChange<K extends keyof JWT>(key: K, value: JWT[K]): void; 
onChange('id', 'def456'); // okay
onChange('expire', new Date(2018, 3, 14)); // okay
onChange('expire', 1337); // error. 1337 not assignable to Date
```

The idea is that the `key` parameter allows the compiler to infer the generic `K` parameter.  Then it requires that `value` matches `JWT[K]`, the indexed access type you need.

Comment: Ran into a problem using a string-valued enum with function members. To handle this well, you can use `type StringValueOf<T> = T[keyof T] & string;`. The best docs I found on string enums are the [TypeScript 2.9 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html)

Comment: Another construct I've found useful is `Required<T>[keyof T]`, which represents the values you can get from `t[k]` when `t: T` and `k in t`.

Comment: @markokraljevic the answer is perfectly valid. You can't assign types as object values as Typescript types (non-primitive types) do not exist at runtime. 

This solution is for creating types that can be more than one type and unify it all in one instead of copy/pasting long lists of types (string | boolean | MyType).

Comment: @jcalz can you help here please? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBlALmZBLY0DeAoa0EqGWA5gE4D2ArgA7QC8O+B0AdmALYCmAXABQA3MCGp8i5dG1IBKXhKmlGAPmatWwSmwiUQ3AHQhKpISLEyA3C3XluyauTbRho7lfUBfADTXoYUnymrvLIktJyCtIqaurQmtq6BkYmLubusbb2js5mbr4eLAUFuFLI3OQAZmDA3NAA8gBGAFYAClT0eASp4qGK6eAN3CAhYaRWxcjwtLUVTkyNre0A2gBEA0MrALpWuPFEOa4QvAttlLRLm4zQS9jdvADkHDwAarn3XtDrw49c3PfeODu9383FernenzAg2+IP+21wuAqlHI-D0yGgnGglAqBzEEBkMQICBQaEw+goNHOnEMUKGfhgs02-EsuAKQA

Comment: Don't forget to add `as const` to the end of the object in question if you are just getting generic string types out of this.

Comment: https://github.com/joonhocho/tsdef has value of

Comment: `type ValueOfFoo = Foo[keyof Foo];  //string | number` is an alternative some might find more direct and readable.

Comment: And as for an array, T[number] can narrow the type for only elements of the array.

By the way, I prefer the following way of declaring types to Enum while using the type in Angular both for TS classes and templates, and the array const can be used for loops. [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBASgUwA4gE5QMpQIZQK4QIQwC8MA2gOQYCqAQgLICSAKiwKIAilANDJXHYApdgGEO3PpQAK7AHKcmcgOIB9AILTpcAPIA1dQBle-UTobTD7CZQC6MbMVCQoAbgBQUAJ5IE8ZGiYOPjEZN6+IABm-ijoWLgERORgeAC2AEYIqLYeQA)

Answer (score 143):

There is another way to extract the union type of the object:

```ts
  const myObj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 'some_string'
  } as const;

  type Values = typeof myObj[keyof typeof myObj];
```

Result union type for `Values` is `1 | "some_string"`

It's possible thanks to the [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) (`as const` part) introduced in TS 3.4.

Comment: This `const` thing is very valuable, TypeScript will actually provide the values themselves and remove duplicates; It's very good for dictionaries.

Comment: This helped me.  If dealing with an enum as a `type`, this can be written
`type MyEnum = { A: 1, B: 'some_string' };  type values = MyEnum[keyof MyEnum];`

Comment: Without `as const` this doesn't work. It only returns the type of the value (not the actual value)
DON'T forget it.

Answer (score 88):

If anyone still looks for implementation of `valueof` for any purposes, this is a one I came up with:

```
type valueof<T> = T[keyof T]
```

Usage:

```
type actions = {
  a: {
    type: 'Reset'
    data: number
  }
  b: {
    type: 'Apply'
    data: string
  }
}
type actionValues = valueof<actions>
```

Works as expected :) Returns an Union of all possible types

Comment: I like this one best as it is clear and explicit in what is being done and `valueof` nicely complements Typescript's existing `keyof` and `typeof` operators. It can even be used with objects rather than types, e.g. `type ObjValues = valueof<typeof obj>`, where `obj` is an associative array.

Comment: Thanks, and as a minor comment to aid any future passers-by, if anyone else is using the _ts-essentials_ lib, you can instead use the `ValueOf` utility type.

Answer (score 30):

With the function below you can limit the value to be the one for that particular key.

```
function setAttribute<T extends Object, U extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: U, value: T[U]) {
    obj[key] = value;
}
```

**Example**

```
interface Pet {
     name: string;
     age: number;
}

const dog: Pet = { name: 'firulais', age: 8 };

setAttribute(dog, 'name', 'peluche')     <-- Works
setAttribute(dog, 'name', 100)           <-- Error (number is not string)
setAttribute(dog, 'age', 2)              <-- Works
setAttribute(dog, 'lastname', '')        <-- Error (lastname is not a property)
```

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T extends any[] ? T[number] : T[keyof T]
```

It works on an array or a plain object.

```
// type TEST1 = boolean | 42 | "heyhey"
type TEST1 = ValueOf<{ foo: 42, sort: 'heyhey', bool: boolean }>
// type TEST2 = 1 | 4 | 9 | "zzz..."
type TEST2 = ValueOf<[1, 4, 9, 'zzz...']>
```

Comment: works only with `ReadonlyArray`: 
`type ValueOf<T> = T extends ReadonlyArray<any> ? T[number] : T[keyof T];`. See https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#valuestypet source

Answer (score 13):

You can made a Generic for your self to get the types of values, **BUT**, please consider the declaration of object should be declared `as const`, like:

```js
export const APP_ENTITIES = {
  person: 'PERSON',
  page: 'PAGE',
} as const; <--- this `as const` I meant
```

Then the below generic will work properly:

```js
export type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
```

Now use it like below:

```js
const entity: ValueOf<typeof APP_ENTITIES> = 'P...'; // ... means typing

   // it refers 'PAGE' and 'PERSON' to you
```

Answer (score 8):

Thanks the existing answers which solve the problem perfectly. Just wanted to add up a lib has included this utility type, if you prefer to import this common one.

https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#valuestypet

```
import { ValuesType } from 'utility-types';

type Props = { name: string; age: number; visible: boolean };
// Expect: string | number | boolean
type PropsValues = ValuesType<Props>;
```

Comment: This is the best answer because this answers handles array too. Other answers don't as lots of property on arrays reflect otherwise

Answer (score 4):

You could use help of generics to define `T` that is a key of JWT and value to be of type `JWT[T]`

```
function onChange<T extends keyof JWT>(key: T, value: JWT[T]);
```

the only problem here is in the implementation that following `obj[key] = value + ' (assigned)';` will not work because it will try to assign `string` to `string & Date`. The fix here is to change index from `key` to `token` so compiler knows that the target variable type is `string`.

Another way to fix the issue is to use Type Guard

```
// IF we have such a guard defined
function isId(input: string): input is 'id' {
  if(input === 'id') {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

// THEN we could do an assignment in "if" block
// instead of switch and compiler knows obj[key] 
// expects string value
if(isId(key)) {
  obj[key] = value + ' (assigned)';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

with [type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest) lib, you can do that with `ValueOf` like that:

```js
import type { ValueOf } from 'type-fest';

export const PATH_NAMES = {
  home: '/',
  users: '/users',
  login: '/login',
  signup: '/signup',
};

interface IMenu {
  id: ValueOf<typeof PATH_NAMES>;
  label: string;
  onClick: () => void;
  icon: ReactNode;
}

  const menus: IMenu[] = [
    {
      id: PATH_NAMES.home,
      label: t('common:home'),
      onClick: () => dispatch(showHome()),
      icon: <GroupIcon />,
    },
    {
      id: PATH_NAMES.users,
      label: t('user:users'),
      onClick: () => dispatch(showUsers()),
      icon: <GroupIcon />,
    },
  ];
```

Comment: In this case `ValueOf` will only return the type of the value instead of the litterral value, so the type of `id` is merely a string rather then the literal union of `'/' | '/users' | '/login' | '/signup'`

Answer (score 2):

*I realize this is slightly off topic, That said every time I've looked for a solution to this. I get sent to this post. So for those of you looking for String Literal Type generator, here you go.*

This will create a string Literal list from an object type.

```
export type StringLiteralList<T, K extends keyof T> = T[keyof Pick<T, K>];

type DogNameType = { name: "Bob", breed: "Boxer" } | { name: "Pepper", breed: "Spaniel" } | { name: "Polly", breed: "Spaniel" };

export type DogNames = StringLiteralList<DogNameType, "name">;

// type DogNames = "Bob" | "Pepper" | "Polly";
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I suggest creating a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Building on @Dima's answer

```
const REGISTRY = 
{
  one: MyClassOne,
  two: MyClassTwo
};

function select(value: keyof typeof REGISTRY): typeof REGISTRY[keyof typeof REGISTRY]
{
  return REGISTRY[value];
}

const myNewthing = new select('one');
```

Answer (score -1):

One-liner:

```js
type ValueTypesOfPropFromMyCoolType = MyCoolType[keyof MyCoolType];
```

Example on a generic method:

```
declare function doStuff<V extends MyCoolType[keyof MyCoolType]>(propertyName: keyof MyCoolType, value: V) => void;
```