# Can I infer the type of a value using extends keyof Type

Tags: typescript, types

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49285864/266535), I asked about assigning a value of a object and the key of an object. Now that I have implemented it, the first function works fine when using the `keyof` but the second does not let me switch on the `key` to narrow down the type.

Below is example code that has comments next to the relevant lines.

```
type JWT = { id: string, token: string, expire: Date };
const obj: JWT = { id: 'abc123', token: 'tk01', expire: new Date(2018, 2, 14) };


function print(key: keyof JWT) {
    switch (key) {
        case 'id':
        case 'token':
            console.log(obj[key].toUpperCase());
            break;
        case 'expire':
            console.log(obj[key].toISOString()); // Works!
            break;
    }
}

function onChange<K extends keyof JWT>(key: K, value: JWT[K]) {
    switch (key) {
        case 'id':
        case 'token':
            obj[key] = value + ' (assigned)';
            break;
        case 'expire':
            obj[key] = value.toISOString(); // Error!
            break;
    }
}
```

How can I implement the `onChange` function so that switch will narrow down the type similar to the `print` function above?

Comment: It's a [design limitation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17859) that TypeScript only narrows the type of the switched `key` and not the related types of `K` or `value`.  Short answer might be that you need to just assert `(value as Date).toISOString()` in that case.

Comment: Uh, of course, `obj[key]` should be a `Date` and not a `string` in that case anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit crazy but I think achieves what you desire ;) It builds upon my answer to your previous question about `valueof`. Also it changes `onChange` signature to accept an object of type `{key: K extends string, value: JWT[K]}`, instead of separate `key` and `value` parameters

```
type JWT = { id: string; token: string; expire: Date }
const obj: JWT = { id: 'abc123', token: 'tk01', expire: new Date(2018, 2, 14) }

function print(key: keyof JWT) {
  switch (key) {
    case 'id':
    case 'token':
      console.log(obj[key].toUpperCase())
      break
    case 'expire':
      console.log(obj[key].toISOString()) // Works!
      break
    default:
      return
  }
}

type ObjectToUnion<
  T extends object,
  U = { [K in keyof T]: { key: K; value: T[K] } }
> = U[keyof U]

function onChange(jwt: ObjectToUnion<JWT>) {
  switch (jwt.key) {
    case 'id': // Try to comment this line and see the error appear at 'exhaustiveCheck'
    case 'token':
      obj[jwt.key] = jwt.value + ' (assigned)'
      return
    case 'expire':
      obj[jwt.key] = jwt.value.toISOString() // Error!
      return
    default:
      // Optionally add exhaustive check to make sure you have covered all cases :)
      const exhaustiveCheck: never = jwt
      return
  }
}
```

You can read more about never type [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/never.html).

I hope that answers your question :)

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Wow, this is super clever! I especially like the `exhaustiveCheck` that errors if one of the cases is missing! I guess the only difference is that calls to `onChange('id', 'def456')` need to be refactored to use `onChange({ key: 'id', value: 'def456' })`