# Get a union type of an interface's member's types

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, it is currently possible to get the union type of all the "keys" of an interface, something like:

```
interface foo {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

function onlyTakeFooKeys(key: keyof foo) {
  // do stuff with key
}
```

And the compiler will enforce that `onlyTakeFooKeys` can only be called with either `name` or `age`.

My use case is that I need to get a union type of the all the types of an interface/object's member. In the given interface `foo` example, I'm expecting something like this:

```
some_operator foo; //=> string | number
```

Is this currently achievable?

Assuming the interfaces have arbitrary number of members which makes hard-coding impossible. And that this needs to be done at compile time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a \`valueof\` similar to \`keyof\` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript)

Answer (score 7):

You can define `ValueOf<T>` like this:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]
```

using [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to index into `T` with `keyof T`.   In your case, you could do `ValueOf<foo>` to produce `string | number`.

This has almost certainly been asked and answered before; my powers of search are failing me at the moment.  This answer is a duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49547901/2887218), but the question as stated is a bit different (as it needed to constrain the key with the value type for that key).

Hope that helps.  Good luck.