# Typescript trying to infer with generics for objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This is what i am trying to accomplish but for an object with generics.
[Is there a `valueof` similar to `keyof` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript).

```
// Something on this lines. I know this is not supported but i am trying to convey the idea here.

type payload<T> = <K extends keyof T>{prop: K, value: T[K]};

const someObj = {a: string, b: number};

type someObjType = payload<someObj>;

const someObjPayload: someObjType = { prop: 'a', value: 'some string'} // should work.

const someObjPayload: someObjType = { prop: 'a', value: 200 } // should throw an error.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately typescript doesn't allow partial inference for variables. If you want to ensure that the value is of the same type as the property specified by `key` you will need o use a helper function to get the apropriate inference behavior:

```
type payload<T, K extends keyof T> = {prop: K, value: T[K]};

let someObj!: {a: string, b: number};

function getProp<K extends keyof typeof someObj>(o: payload<typeof someObj, K>) {
  return o
}

const someObjPayload = getProp({ prop: 'a', value: 'some string'}) // ok of type payload<{ a: string; b: number; }, "a">

const someObjPayload2= getProp({prop: 'a', value: 100}) // error
```

Answer (score 1):

Since only `number` and `string` are allowed in TypeScript, it might be simpler to just write everything two times - leaving your type parameter `K` out

```
type stringKeyPayload<T> = {prop: string, value: T}
type numberKeyPayload<T> = {prop: number, value: T}
```

Comment: Sorry for the lame answer :D  I recently had a similar problem and came up with that solution

Comment: The problem with your answer is that `value` should be a type taht is a property type of `T` not `T` (ie `T[keyof T]`) And the problem OP wants to solve is to ensure the value is of the same type as the property specified by `K` ..

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for pointing that out. @Titian's answer looks way better