# Probleme with generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I don't know why I have an error message

> teste.ts:41:18 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.

in the following code

```
function carre1<T>(x: T):T {
    x = Math.pow(x, 2);
    return x;
}
console.log(carre1<number>(0));
console.log(carre1<number>(2));
console.log(carre1<number>(5));
```

Comment: Because Math.pow can *only* take numbers. You could try `<T extends number>`, but basically this is a bad candidate for a generic function.

Comment: Thank you jonrsharpe for your message , but same errore.

Comment: function carre1<T extends number>(x: T) {
    x = Math.pow(x, 2);
    return x;
}

console.log(carre1<number>(0)); // 0
console.log(carre1<number>(2)); // 4
console.log(carre1<number>(5)); // 25

Comment: No, you get a *different* error. The point that a function where you know what types are needed isn't a useful demonstration of generics stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are trying to explore generics and its usages. Perhaps the function that you have just shared is not really a good case study for generics. The first parameter of **Math.pow** is expected to be a **number type**, which is why you are getting the error. Imagine if you are invoking the function as such:

```
console.log(carre1<string>("abc"));
```

It will cause runtime error, which is why it was prevented by TS transpilation process in the first place.

If we look at the function from a functionality perspective, there is no need for it to be generic at all. It is understood to be a number already. The function could then be written as something like following, without generics:

```
function carre1(x: number): number {
    x = Math.pow(x, 2);
    .... some other logics?
    return result;
}
```

However, if we insist on using generic parameter, perhaps the following can be considered. Though the generics are not being useful in this case:

```
function carre1<T>(x: T ): T {
    let y:any = Math.pow(x as any, 2);
    return y;
}
```

Consider this following function. It could be a useful example of Generics as the function should be able to accept parameter of any type. In another word, the function logic is type independent.

```
function deepCopy<T>(data: T): T {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Another good use case of generics could be implementing a Data or Object Mapper. Refer to this example shared here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52759912/6096478

Comment: thank you for all these explanations, it is much clearer for me!

Comment: No problem. Glad it helps!

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript knows it is a number:

```
function carre1<T>(x: T):T {
  // x must be a number because Math.pow only takes a number
    x = Math.pow(x, 2);  
    return x;
}
```

Generics are most useful for specialising functions that take an object as a parameter.

```
interface HasXProp {
  x: number
}

function carre1<T extends HasXProp>(something: T): T {
    const x = Math.pow(something.x, 2);  
    return { ...something, x };
}
```

Comment: Hello Josh , thank you for your help ,but i meet little error in the code ,` "teste.ts:60:49 - error TS1005: '?' expected.

60 function carre1<T>(something: T extends HasXProp): T {" `  I put optional parameters "?" but without success.

Comment: I fixed that. Putting the `extends` statement in the parameter typing, versus the Generic parameter, makes it part of a ternary.