# Create string literal type from object type's string values

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

We are currently using TS 2.3 (can't upgrade to 2.4 at the moment so using enums for this isn't an option).

We have an object type for something that looks like this

```
type myObject = {
  keyOn: 'valueOne';
  keyTwo: 'valueTwo';
  keyThree: 'valueThree;
}
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to create a type that is made up of the string literals that are the values on that object type. So something like this:

```
type valueLiterals = 'valueOne' | 'valueTwo' | 'valueThree'
```

Similar to what you would be able to produce for the keys by using

```
type objectKeys = keyOf myObject
```

Is there some version of a `valueof` or similar that would allow automatic generation of the `valueLiterals` type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a `valueof` similar to `keyof` in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a type query with `keyof T`:

```
type values = myObject [keyof myObject]
```