# How does typescript FunctionPropertyNames work?

Tags: typescript

```js
type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never }[keyof T];
```

I know mapped type `{ [P in keyof T]: T[P] }` and `keyof`, but how do they work together and filter `never`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If never is present in a union, it is removed from the union. So `never | "A"` will just be `"A"`.

Given this behavior, we want to construct a mapped type that has `never` as the type for the keys we don't want in the result, and the name of the key as the type of the key for the keys we want in the result. We do this using the conditional type `T[K] extends Function ? K : never` on each property. So for example:

```
type FunctionPropertyNamesMapped<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never }
type Test = FunctionPropertyNamesMapped<{
    a: number,
    fn: () => {}
}>
// Test is the same as
// {
//    a: never;
//    fn: "fn";
//}
```

Given this new mapped type, if we get a union of all key types in it (using `[keyof T]`) we would get the union `never | "fn"` which reduces to just `"fn"`

You can also listen to my audio explanation of something similar [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Swrzqr4MSs&t=1404s)

Comment: let `type Foo = { P1: V1, P2: V2, P3: V3  }    type Bar = P1 | P2`, `Foo[Bar]` will be `V1 | V2`? I haven't seen this usage in typescript documentation. Do you have any links?

Comment: @Zen yes `Foo[keyof Foo]` will be `V1 | V2`. Looking for official docs about that... but the handbook does not say anything explicit about it as far as I can tell..

Comment: Never mind, I found it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript

Comment: @Zen not exactly official reference, but I would take jcalz word for it. Then again you could take my word for it too :P