# How make merge all values of an interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to merge all values of an interface, for example:

```js
interface IA {
    a: string;
}
interface IB {
    b: string;
}
interface IC {
    c: string;
}
//...

interface IMap {
    "a": IA;
    "b": IB;
    "c": IC;
    //...
    "z": IZ;
}
```

Is there a way to create a type like:

```js
type IAll = IMap["a"] & IMap["b"] & IMap["c"] & ... & IMap["z"];
```

I'm trying using this both:

```js
type valueMerge<T> = T[keyof T];
type valueMerge2<T extends keyof IMap = keyof IMap> = IMap[T];

// using
let t: valueof<IMap> = null as any;
let t2: valueof2 = null as any;
```

But for each one, the type is `IA | IB | IC | ... | IZ` and not `IA & IB & IC & ... & IZ`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simlar to a question about [how to programmatically turn a union into an intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type), and it has a similar solution.

Normally when you do a [lookup of all the properties of an object type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49286056/2887218), you get a union of all the properties, as you saw.  The problem is that `keyof T` is a *union* of the property keys, and looking up a union of keys gives you a union of properties, because property lookup is *covariant* in the property key type... but what you want is an operation *contravariant* in the property key type.  (You can read more about covariance/contravariance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)), but basically covariance implies that a union input becomes a union output, while contravariance implies a union input becomes an intersection output).

Luckily [function arguments are contravariant](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#strict-function-types), so if we can map your interface to a new one where the old property types are function arguments, we can get to a place where a union of these function types can result in the intersection of their arguments.  And [type inference in conditional types using the `infer` keyword](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-inference-in-conditional-types) can do this for us (see the line that says "if any candidates were inferred from contra-variant positions, the type inferred is an *intersection* of those candidates").

Here's the code:

```
type IntersectProperties<T> = { [K in keyof T]: (x: T[K]) => void } extends {
  [K in keyof T]: (k: infer I) => void
}
  ? I
  : never;
```

The properties of `T` are mapped to function arguments, and then we `infer` a single type `I` corresponding to *all* the function arguments, which will be an intersection.

Let's see if it works:

```
type IAll = IntersectProperties<IMap>;
// type IAll = IA & IB & IC & ... & IZ
```

Looks good.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEFkG8CwAoZZOALmQGcwpQBzAbnwF99RJZEVUAhbfQgI1IUqIOo2bho8JGgDCPAsgSDKNeniZ4A9JoB0e8aykcAWvMIAvZcNHr8ByezQBZOAAczRUhjX8vnH4peMgHaejq8yJZoxmoa+GAAnq4oAKogwAD2IAAqGagSUGQQCGCZIAA8KQB8yAC8yAAUKcgQAB6QIAAmZEQgCREA-I0A1qQpAJR1NQBuGcCdEaQgENPQk20d3Y0No8igMNBok7Uzc53jg2iLyMurUGrxSRwFRSUAClAZyVClEGTl2Rq9SwyAA2gBpPYgZDDCAJDIwZDZAC6pAarVI2QhyOOp3myAYLXaEC6PVwCghUJhcIRSNRI1I+0OqFxyFm8zECiGqGut2gDzwiWSaHQABtRXU0C9imAPl9oL9-qgXK4qmptMghRwxRL6hhkAAyNDcI2oORGsKG6J2PD4IA)