# How to typeguard filtering Object.entries?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I wish there was something like `entryof` to typeguard entries like this:

```js
const carDude = {
  name: "Tom",
  age: 45,
  car: "Porsche 911"
}

interface Dude {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

Object
  .entries(carDude)
  .filter((entry): entry is entryof Dude => 
    entry[0] === "name" || entry[0] === "age"
  )
```

How to work around that using a typeguard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be inclined to define `EntryOf` like this:

```
type EntryOf<T extends object> = { [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T];
```

That will take an object type `T` and make it into a union of entry tuples.  Then your code could be written as

```
const ret = Object.entries(carDude).filter((entry): entry is EntryOf<Dude> =>
    entry[0] === "name" || entry[0] === "age"
);
/* const ret: (["name", string] | ["age", number])[] */
```

and you see that the returned array type has elements of type `["name", string] | ["age", number]`, as I assume you wanted.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: Very cool, thanks! I'm even understanding that except the last part: What's the `[keyof T]` saying at the end?

Comment: It's [looking up](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the values. `{[K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]}` looks like `{name: ["name", string]; age: ["age", number]}`, so I'm looking up the `["name" | "age"]` property values of that.  See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49286056/2887218).