# How to get value types from a Typescript interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given some interface:

```
interface IFoo {
    userService: IUserService
    authService: IAuthService
}
```

How do I retrieve `IUserService` and `IAuthService` via the following function:

```
function getInternalTypes<T>() {
    // Need to loop through T (somehow) and extract those types, for example to do something like:
    // IoCContainer.Resolve<K>(KString); // where K is the type IUserService and KString is the string "IUserService".
}
```

I know you can use `keyof` to get keys but not sure how I would go about getting the actual types for these keys (`typeof`? I don't know...)

Comment: Are you asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript)?  What specifically are you expecting `getInternalTypes()` to output?

Comment: What do you want to "extract those types" into?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Asumming I have access to a `type ValType` and a `string ValTypeString`, I'd like to `IoCContainer.resolve<ValType>(ValTypeString)`.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for suggesting that thread, I'll take a look.

Comment: @jcalz Using that link, I'd say I might be able to get a union of all value types, but I still don't know how I'd extract these one at a time. Further to my comment above, inside my `getInternalTypes` function, I'd like to be able to go `IoCContainer.resolve<K>(KString)` where `K` is the type `IUserService` (for example) and (if possible, but not necessary), `KString` is the string `"IUserService"`.

Comment: Have edited the question to reflect this.