# Create a union from values of a nested object with different keys

Tags: typescript

Given I have the following `Options` Type

```
interface Options {
  parent1: {
    child1: {
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  };
  parent2: {
    child2: {
      baz: 'daz'
    }
  };
}
```

How can I turn it into a union of all 2nd level child property values, in this case

```
{ foo: 'bar' } | { baz: 'daz' }
```

I tried the following

```
type KnownOptions = Options[keyof Options][keyof Options[keyof Options]];
```

But that only works if the 2nd level child properties are the same across all top level properties. E.g. it works when I rename `child2` to `child1

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM7IDeAsAFDLLpxQTgCMAXEWRRQgBbAA2AJo8%20VYUY2bEwDkAI2riWrAL5z5AbjlUa4AExMSgtp17aBQitIBeEnnDOy9yRYJVkHZMAE90KANIhsAdxAMLFwCAF40TBx8AG0Aawg3bBgI4PwAXTiEpJSovEzE5KDctLTlIA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to fetch the nested type:

```
type KnownOptions<T> = T extends {
  [k in keyof T]: {
    [k: string]: infer OptionValue
  }
} ? OptionValue : never

// Good:
const a: KnownOptions<Options> = { foo: 'bar' }
const b: KnownOptions<Options> = { baz: 'daz' }

// Expect errors:
const c: KnownOptions<Options> = { foo: 'bad value' }
const d: KnownOptions<Options> = { badKey: 'bar' }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=24&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM7IDeAsAFDLLpxQTgCMAXEWRRQgBbAA2AJo8+VYUY2bEwDkAI2riWrAL5z5AbjlUa4AExMSgtp17aBQitIBeEnnDOy9yRYJVkHZMAE90KANIhsAdxAMLFw8AB4AFQA+ZABeZHDkCAAPSBAeAl0KAG0Aa2RQZByIN2wYeIBdHTlsnKY8MChQAHNK-JAYaDRMHBAANTguAFcIJWdkAH4u4L6B4eQmEAgAN2gyMgB6deQAcVEeBjIEELBkOCYff0DukNCgnrxouMJkETFkKRl7Q+PkSXPfAJ3G5A-CPIi-ayWaziL6kDZbACiSU8CBO0Cg2CgeAOpCO+BOCH+lxBYRJYOerwk0h4yCWswgMIcePqyH2yAugOu+FuXIesXB1K8xSpnwcQA)

This is a generic type that accepts a type that has two levels of keys.  The conditional type (noted by the ternary `T extends Type ? A : B`) says "if the generic type T is an object at least 2 level deeps, then return the type at each of those that second levels. Else, return the `never` type, because the generic type is invalid.

The `infer OptionalValue` says "whatever type is here, save that as `OptionValue`". This is then returned by the conditional type, after multiple type have been saved to it, creating a union of each type.

I have to admit, I'm not entire sure why the first level key needed to be `k in keyof T` but the second level could just be `k: string`. But, that was the only way I got it to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

I would write `KnownOptions` like this:

```
type KnownOptions = { [K in keyof Options]: Options[K][keyof Options[K]] }[keyof Options];
```

Here we're [mapping](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) each property of `Options` to a union of *its* properties, and then uniting all of those unions together.  It might make more sense if we write it in terms of [`ValueOf<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49286056/2887218) defined like this:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

type KO = ValueOf<{ [K in keyof Options]: ValueOf<Options[K]> }>;
```

So `ValueOf<T>` gives you a union of the property value types of an object `T` (e.g., `ValueOf<{a: string, b: number}>` is `string | number`) and so what you're doing is mapping each property of `Options` with `ValueOf` and then taking `ValueOf` the whole thing.

You can verify that each of those definitions evaluates to `{foo: "bar";} | {baz: "daz";}` as desired.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM7IDeAUMmcunFBOAIwBcRp5LCAFsADYAmDTLA8jGzZGAcgBGVMc0EBfZLORyA3EsrVwAJkYlBZdl247++llIBe47nAsyzcpauKPiYAJ7oUAaRDYA7iAYWLgEALxEyADa3sigyADWEO7YMGiYOPgAuozBmXgxWVFJKWl5oYVZysXJqekh2WpunigAanCcAK4QqDAAPAAqAHzIEQM1pcgDWU0eXsjeqKPI7V09-YTRsfEldeXZjKvdvX37Bd5ZI3JDKkA)

Answer (score 0):

you can index into the type with the `['propName']` notation to extract the type

`type KnownOptions  = Options['parent1']['child1'] | Options['parent2']['child2']`