# Typescript: Transform a union of objects to a plain union

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to transform a union of objects to a plain union with object's values. An example:

```js
type Foo = {};
type Bar = {};
type Baz = {};
type Qux = {};

type Input = {
  foo: Foo,
  bar: Bar,
} | {
  bar: Bar,
  baz: Baz,
} | {
  qux: Qux,
};

type Expected = Foo | Bar | Baz | Qux;
```

Pay attention that keys of union's objects may intersect (`bar` in example). Hope the solution advance me unwrapping nested typings.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAvgbgLAChSRQBCAhgE7JpZ4HSkBelGO+40AigK4AeT1uNNlACSAOzCdgTPFCgAzBAC5YCADQyoAI3LLSZdbnRQAPmg3ayu8gdnb6V+gaOnUGgI49lXbk5Z4A9P4i4pJQALQAfFAA8pISwIKEACpkJKIAzgpkALYAPElRKEl+rIQAotyQAMbAEAAmlPCIpnomxCSMpt4sQA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to take something like [a `ValueOf<T>` type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript) (which is just `T[keyof T]`) and *distribute* it across the union members of `T` so that if `T` is, for example,  `A | B | C`, then `Transform<T>` is `A[keyof A] | B[keyof B] | C[keyof C]`.  You can use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to get that behavior:

```
type Transform<T> = T extends any ? T[keyof T] : never;
```

Let's test it:

```
type Output = Transform<Input>
// type Output = Foo | Bar | Baz | Qux
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKAzBAuKBnYAJwEsA7AcygF8BuAWAChRIoAhAQ0OTSgCNPcBEhWr0m4aBwBe3dPymCiZSrUbNoARQCuAD1lQAjrsXCVYtRKgBJUmC3BZjKJhywEAGid8BbTp4ZUUAA+aF78hLgchP7O8pHsUv6BIaheRjq42jpJ5gwA9HnWtvZQALQAfFAA8vZ2wBYsACqE7KR4WIQAtgA8jZUojVAQOsAQpAAmeFCtIFAA-FCNANoA1hAgcBiLALpQuKQQAG4QhLnq1bUlAy1tHT02deWMBVDnNcB13PCIIVHBvjIQlkGtAAKI6SAAY1G4y+CH+f1+CX+WTEQA)