# Can I make a key-value dictionary in TypeScript that's typesafe for every key-value pair?

Tags: typescript, dictionary, types

This question's kind of involved, and possibly best approached by exploring a rudimentary state system, so walk with me here for a minute. Suppose I have this state class:

```
class AccountState {
  public id: string;
  public displayName: string;
  public score: number;
}
```

From [jcalz's work here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49286056/254830), I know I can build a function that references any AccountState property in a typesafe way—I can take a property name and value, and impose the property's own type restriction on that value using generics, which is pretty impressive:

```
class Store {
  state = new AccountState();

  mutate<K extends keyof AccountState>(property: K, value: AccountState[K]): void {
    this.state[property] = value;
  }
}

const store = new Store();
store.mutate('displayName', 'Joseph Joestar'); // ok
store.mutate('displayName', 5); // not ok: surfaces the below typescript error
// ts(2345) Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

Using the `ValueOf<T>` in jcalz's answer, I can also model a sort-of-typesafe key-value dictionary. It'd probably be easiest for me to show you how it works, as well as its shortcomings, in action:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

class Store {
  state = new AccountState();

  mutateMany(updates: { [key in keyof AccountState]?: ValueOf<AccountState> }): void {
    Object.keys(updates).forEach(property => {
      const value = updates[property];
      (this.state[property] as any) = value;
    });
  }
}

const store = new Store();
store.mutateMany({ displayName: 'Joseph Joestar', score: 5 }); // ok
store.mutateMany({ displayName: 1000, score: 'oh no' }); // unfortunately, also ok
store.mutateMany({ score: true }); // not ok, surfaces the below error
// ts(2322) Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'ValueOf<AccountState>'.
// (if AccountState had a boolean property, this would be allowed)
```

That second `mutateMany()` is an issue. As you can see, I can require that the key is some property of AccountState. I can also require that the value corresponds to some property on AccountState, so it has to be `string | number`. However, there is no requirement that the value corresponds to the property's actual type.

How can I make the dictionary fully typesafe, so that e.g. `{ displayName: 'a', score: 1 }` is allowed but `{ displayName: 2, score: 'b' }` is not?

I've considered declaring an AccountStateProperties interface which simply repeats all those properties and their values, then defining `mutateMany(updates: AccountStateProperties)`, but that would add up to a lot of code duplication for more involved state objects. I didn't know I could do some of these things until today, and I'm wondering if the typing system has something I can leverage here to make this dictionary fully typesafe without that approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `mutateMany` method, `[key in keyof AccountState]?: ValueOf<AccountState>`, you're saying that for any `key`, the type of the value can be any type that `AccountState` has. You can see this demonstrated if you try an update with something that's not in `AccountState` (like `true`).

Instead, I believe you want:

```
mutateMany(updates: { [key in keyof AccountState]?: AccountState[key] })
```

This says that the value at `key` should additionally match the type of `AccountState` at `key` and not just any of the types of the values for `AccountState`.

[edit: If you look at that linked answer, the section that starts with "In order to make sure that the key/value pair "match up" properly in a function, you should use generics as well as lookup types..." describes this]

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. :) I used the section you're referencing in the `mutate()` case, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work for me in the `mutateMany()` case.

Answer (score 2):

For `mutateMany()`, I think the version that works and doesn't require *too* much unsafety is to have `updates` be of type `Pick<AccountState, K>`, where `K` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be keys from `AccountState`, and where we're using the [`Pick<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys).  A value of type `Pick<AccountState, K>` will have all the properties from `AccountState` at the keys in `K`.

Here's how one might write it:

```
class Store {
    state = new AccountState();
    mutateMany<K extends keyof AccountState>(updates: Pick<AccountState, K>): void {
        (Object.keys(updates) as Array<K>).forEach(<P extends K>(property: P) => {
            this.state[property] = updates[property];
        });
    }
}
```

The only unsafe thing going on here is that we [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that `Object.keys(updates)` will return only the keys in `K`.  The compiler doesn't actually know this, because object types in TypeScript are not closed; it may well be that `updates` has more properties than the compiler knows about.  See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript) for more info.

Let's see how it works:

```
const store = new Store();
store.mutateMany({ displayName: 'Joseph Joestar', score: 5 }); // ok
store.mutateMany({ displayName: 1000, score: 'oh no' }); // error!
// --------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~  ----> ~~~~~
// number isn't string,         string isn't number

store.mutateMany({ displayName: "okay", randomProp: 123 });  // error!
// -----------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Object literal may only specify known properties
```

Looks good.  The errors show up where we expect them.

---

Note that the issue with extra keys in `updates` is prevented above if you pass in an object literal, due to [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).  But if you don't use a fresh object literal, it's possible to do weird things:

```
const badMutation = {
    displayName: "okay",
    randomProp: 123
}
const aliasedMutation: { displayName: string } = badMutation;
store.mutateMany(aliasedMutation); // no error here
```

This is unlikely, so you might not care.  If you do care, the type system in TypeScript can't really stop it, so you'd need to protect yourself at runtime with some extra check like

```
        if (["id", "displayName", "score"].includes(property))
            this.state[property] = updates[property];
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCzAPYFcB2AXAyus6Cm0A3gFDRnQAOyARiAJbDR0AmAXNBOgE52oDm0ALzQARCIDcpclVoNozOhArgAngDkwAWzztOPfkNESpZGfUYQkXHdFTJN1PF0MAGSQF9iX0JBjZE1kQmHDj4hqh4AO5wCCgY2Lh4ABQAlJLk0JrIoXgAsmCoKgA8ANLQeAAe+KjMMADWeCqIAGYxSGhYOQB8ScgUzIkQ7AAKDHVF8O3xOQA00CVdKewAbogsQRkZSQDy1ABWeMDoAHQNKhC9-YMp0JBwXFxgxQspx80BAKJgwAAWSUXDcpVPA1GALJIULiIChOdAqEY3QRdDabVF0VpJADaIhYIjmIgUSlUGm0eNElgCeBEAF1jrxQMhmHgLpDobCVCkUsFUaj0D9FMdOIlMayYVw4dTDH0BvgICKoWKJekee40sFPJ5iEhUJwQpTwlFoP5rKlJJxKccsjl8oUkoR5IplE8STYAOQAKUQEDwFB+0E9zJwXFdcwp1nYAFZoKrxNAAPRx6CIOrEc3WS3ZRI2lR2h1E51aGwARhcpdDVjdiD9qEQrujaXjiacUK4AEJiAnoABaHu9vt95EAP2HI9Hg7IA+gY47ibsDicTAgqFd6BC+j4cx5a94AkUy9Xc8cXC8abwGetBRz9sJTvUhfYImTTzJjxqiE0wwV7CLACYAMz1rGjblA8ATtp2-aQVB0EwUOY7wSOM7QLsBxHNA9D4I8ICZE8SaoCAKgcDCwDooRdQ1pEqCUAqsJ0My3iIDqq7UGAzC5Jm6B0IxhgkBkN7EveohPioeLBK+zDvp+0Lfv+xCeNqupgPQkB4GxHFcag7DXo6AnaLo3A7tGhgsWpoQaWa6AWlaWaXkkSl0Cppm4BpDadjWIEttAPxOHgXhAA)

Comment: This is excellent. Today I learned about Pick!