# How can I use a property key (object.key) in a TypeScript Enum?

Tags: typescript, enums

I'd like to convert some JS arrays into [TypeScript enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html).

I know I can do:

```
export enum FRUIT {
  PEACH,
  BANANA
}
```

But in this case 'FRUITS' is exported from a separate file, and has the format:

```
const FRUIT = {
  PEACH: "delicious peach",
  BANANA: "wow a banana that's awesome",
  PEAR: "gross pear do not allow pear using the Enum"
};
```

(I want to ensure only a subset of fruits, eg "delicious peach" can be set for ACCEPTABLE_FRUIT  )

I need to do:

```
export enum ACCEPTABLE_FRUIT {
  FRUITS.PEACH,
  FRUITS.BANANA
}
```

However this is a syntax error:

> Only numeric enums can have computed members, but this expression has type 'string'. If you do not need exhaustiveness checks, consider using an object literal instead.

**How can I use a property key (object.key) in a TypeScript Enum?** Alternatively, if I can't, how can I get around the syntax error?

Comment: What _is_ `FRUITS`? You seem to be trying to use the _values_ from it as _names_, which doesn't make much sense - do you want e.g. `export enum FRUIT_TYPES { PEACH = FRUIT.PEACH, ... }`? Or maybe something where you can only use e.g. `keyof typeof FRUITS` (like `"PEACH"`) as a value? How would you use this once you've created it?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include this information.

Comment: And is that set of strings `keyof typeof FRUIT`? Please put this in the question, along with an example showing how you intend to _use_ it.

Comment: It sounds like you want a `valueof` equivalent, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49286056/3001761, an enum isn't the right direction.

Comment: Try it in the playground - `type FRUIT_NAMES = keyof typeof FRUIT` would be `"PEACH" | "BANANA" | "PEAR"`.

Comment: [Try it in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYgJQKoEkAqMC8MDeAoGGABQFEBBAYQAkAuGAIgBMBTAGwEth2QBXCGAA7MAhsAAW9ADR4AvgG48eKAE8h8ZOgD6AOTIBZEgGUsMANbNlIAGYwVQ6+tRoFQA)

Comment: [Edit] the question. Please provide the actual context, this seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - for example, if you're asking about a subset, having an example with only one member isn't helpful.

Comment: Then yes, you probably want a "valueof" with either `Pick` ("only peach or banana") or `Omit` ("not pear") - see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html. That's not going to get you to an enum, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't get you an enum, but if your goal is just to be able to able to express *"either `FRUIT.PEACH` or `FRUIT.BANANA`"* you don't need one.

- First, you need the values of `FRUIT` to be typed more specifically than `string`, which you can do with `as const` (see [literal inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-inference)):

  ```
  const FRUIT = {
    PEACH: "delicious peach",
    BANANA: "wow a banana that's awesome",
    PEAR: "gross pear do not allow pear using the Enum"
  } as const;
  ```
- Second, you want a "valueof" type as shown in [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz)'s answer to [Is there a `valueof` similar to `keyof` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript):

  ```
  type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
  ```
- Finally you can use the `Pick` or `Omit` [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) to select the props from `typeof FRUIT` you want to include:

  ```
  type ACCEPTABLE_FRUIT = ValueOf<Pick<typeof FRUIT, "PEACH" | "BANANA">>;
  // type ACCEPTABLE_FRUIT = "delicious peach" | "wow a banana that's awesome";
  ```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QPIDMA8AVAfFAXimwG0BrCEAe3WIF0AoBgYyoDsBnYKAMQCUAqgElshKAG8GUKAAUAogEEAwgAkAXFABEAEwgIAls31UkHKJDjMAFpoA0UqACEFAOVcKNmgO5UvUOFAARnBsIQHAVnDAAORmcF4QHFQAthB2DvIKfJ4A5gBOVBxmFnlQ2lRQbFTciAi+5hBwpab6bDlQEdBybEjJmgwAvv5mrJzAANxMoJBQykpyMtgKjgAycgD6-MKiRPDIaFioyfrAmNMQNLyCIrZamXyauLiTDOhIbMzAxmxQ6HlIJwAspYrK0IAAKXQcZh5fRgL7sDRzBZLVYbLYiACUGgAblR9NoJAMmH8AcBgdYweCdHpDMZTA0QZpMZNSUCQVTvPUAsFQqEOpEYnEEklUszWf92ZS2BDNPlCsVGqVypVqv4EHU-CUoC02gKuj0+izXpLyRyZdTRRAIq12noONAIGwvnk9CBxQwgA)

Comment: Just wanted to acknowledge you were right earlier when you said this was an y/x problem. I thought enums were the only way to restrict values in this situation but obviously not.