# Typescript - create a type from certain key of array

Tags: typescript

If I have a type like

```
export interface MyObject {
  id: number
  title: string
}
```

and I create an array like this

```
const myArray: MyObject[] = [
  {
    id: 2358,
    title: 'Item 1'
  },
  {
    id: 85373,
    title: 'Item 2'
  }
]
```

Is there a way to define a type that only allows values that have appeared as an id in the array? So in this case it would look like.

```
type DesiredType = 2358 | 85373
```

[Here is a link to a Codewich](https://codewich.com/#v1,,,hY_NasMwEIRz1lPMzS2EhFp1EwwuBHrpofTSm_FBsTauiiwFSQmIknev5fxATaG33WXm2xllArmdaAlv8X37RW3ANwOULGEO_ZbcsAQVNJXwwSnTsRNjrTU.oI8b50Qs4UhIa3S8IeoGFerBmVBnWM6L9XzcLrTsNVCPh2y4nea_pOuCr_gf2nzUsgbCY0xwDaKkH_5d4ix6sb_TqJ6hF0reMxbinvBCXjmSH2mukE52l3z1uWRzRR2FVnLjvepMTyaUE2Nqcftq_hHzxwLLJfynPWiJTh0J5Jx1E0BST61ZznP.lDE2m_0A) where I have tried a few things to no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a \`valueof\` similar to \`keyof\` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the type of `id` in `myArray` you can use a type query: `typeof myArray[number]['id']`. The problem is that the type of `id` is not preserverd in the type of `myArray`.

To preserve the type you can use `as const` (but you loose the MyObject constraint)

```
const myArray = [
    {
        id: 2358,
        title: 'Item 1'
    },
    {
        id: 85373,
        title: 'Item 2'
    }
] as const;

type Id = typeof myArray[number]['id']
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWQE8B5AIwCtht4BvAKDkcQBMAuOJAVwFtS0GmMBDAA2wdgGcYUZAHM6AXzrYISKXG6EAglCiZCcALxwA2gMb0mVluwBMAZgCsADgA0560NHi4AcgCSqNxwAIy+HgruVpbWjAhscM6O9gDs9lGxcF5i7AFBcLbhVkoAunCYEnAqajAA3HR0MIRgeP7MRlnNwBDoGtq6+iZcvGglJr7xviVAA)

Or you can use a helper function:

```
function makeMyObjectArray<V extends number>(...a: Array<MyObject & { id: V}>) {
    return a;
}
const myArray = makeMyObjectArray(
    {
        id: 2358,
        title: 'Item 1'
    },
    {
        id: 85373,
        title: 'Item 2'
    }
)

type Id = typeof myArray[number]['id']
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWQE8B5AIwCtht4BvAKDkcQBMAuOJAVwFtS0GmMBDAA2wdgGcYUZAHM6AXzp10nJNQQQkcbpgDWwImUrUAglCiZCAHgBqcUKiTMJHHnygA+ABQA6f5js5pY2RhRU8ABkcDQs7LYKngCUMQKMUMAwnFDamADcinTYWlI6hMFWcAC8OvqGJOFmFlbeaalMHXFwAEwAzACsABwANG0dQqLicADkAJKo3HAAjNNtCqMd9J1MCGxwg-29AOy9G9twE2Lscws9qx1KScowhGB4s8zVF6-AEOhlFUIAG0uLw0ABdIHTXbTcFAA)

Comment: The second solution with the helper function works perfectly for my use case. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new type that has the type of the `id` property using, for example, `Pick`:

```
type MyObjectIdType = Pick<typeof myArray[number], 'id'>;
```

The problem here is that the array is a dynamic value and the compiler will infer the type as the most generic one, i.e., `number`. To have the compiler use the actual values of the `id` property you must tell it that the array is, in fact, a compile-time constant:

```
const myArray = [
    {
        id: 2358,
        title: 'Item 1'
    },
    {
        id: 85373,
        title: 'Item 2'
    }
] as const;
```

Note that for this to work I had to remove the type declaration `MyObject[]` from `myArray`, because a generic array of `MyObject` it is not compatible with the constant declaration (it may have more or less than 2 elements, with `id`s different from the given ones).

Obviously, this means that if you want to operate on a dynamic array, generated at runtime (and I expect you'd want), this will not work.

Comment: The brackets in the first code snippet here do not match.