# Union type from key of another type

Tags: typescript

I have a type as below

```
type IdAndName = {
 id: number;
 name: string;
}
```

Then I need a type that will be union from the values of keys of above type as follow -

```
type IdOrName = number | string;
```

Is there any way to achieve this dynamically?

Comment: `type Values<T> = T[keyof T];  type IdOrNumber = Values<IdAndName>`

Comment: Why don't use `any` type ?

Comment: I believe this question is a dublicate, but I can't find the original question

Comment: I believe you meant: `from the values of above type as follow` instead of keys

Comment: Yes, from the values of keys :) Updated the question

Comment: @AbhinandanKhilari please see my first comment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a \`valueof\` similar to \`keyof\` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript)

Comment: Tried both `Values<IdAndName>` and `ValueOf<IdAndName>`, but getting errors for both -  `Cannot find name 'Values'` and `Cannot find name 'ValueOf'` respectively. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @AbhinandanKhilari you need to write  your own `Values` type. Please see my first comment

Comment: Oh, my bad. I missed that.

Comment: @captain-yossarian thanks, that works! By the way, can you help me with a link to official docs for creating such generic types? I am unable to locate that. Would like to go through it to understand.

Comment: @AbhinandanKhilari here you have https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-types.html