# How to use typeof with generics?

Tags: typescript

How do I use `typeof` with generics?

For example:

```
const obj = {
  a: 2,
  b: "asd"
} as const;

const values: typeof Object.values<typeof obj> = /* some code */
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a \`valueof\` similar to \`keyof\` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript)

Comment: `type Values<T> = T[keyof T]` and then `const values: Values<typeof obj> = 2 // ok`

Comment: @captain-yossarian No, I'm looking for a generalized solution, this is just a basic example.

Comment: `typeof Object.values<typeof obj>` syntax is invalid in both javascript and typescript. What do you mean more generalized example? Do you want to overload `Object.values` method?