# inferring arguments types based on others

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to infer the type of a subset of arguments, based on some other arguments in typescript? See an example below

```
type FormValues = {
  name: string;
  height: number;
  birthDate: Date;
}


const [value, setValue] = useState<Partial<FormValues>>({});

const setFieldValue = (field: keyof FormValues, value: FormValues[field]) => {
  setValue(prev => ({ ...prev, field: value }));
}
```

I know why wouldn't it work. But couldn't verify that it's either not possible in typescript or there is an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add extra generic.

```js
type FormValues = {
  name: string;
  height: number;
  birthDate: Date;
}


const [value, setValue] = useState<Partial<FormValues>>({});

const setFieldValue = <Field extends keyof FormValues>(field: Field, value: FormValues[Field]) => {
  setValue(prev => ({ ...prev, field: value }));
}
```

[Here](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments), in my article, you can find more techniques of arguments infering

Comment: thank you for the answer and the blog post.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in [the answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49286056/8599834), you can do as follows:

```js
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];


type FormValues = {
  name: string;
  height: number;
  birthDate: Date;
}


const [value, setValue] = useState<Partial<FormValues>>({});

const setFieldValue = (field: keyof FormValues, value: ValueOf<FormValues>) => {
  setValue(prev => ({ ...prev, field: value }));
}
```

and any type used by a property of FormValues will pass validation.