# Object literals combining enums and computed property names

Tags: typescript, typescript4.0

I have an enum

```js
enum Action {
  action1 = 'action1',
  action2 = 'action2'
};
```

whose values I use as computed property names in an object:

```js
/*
  ...to be able to use these as values, not just types
*/
const ActionState = {
  [Action.action1]: 'actionState1' as const,
  [Action.action2]: 'actionState2' as const,
};
```

I'd like to define a type / an interface whose keys are template literals mapping an `Action` to the corresponding `ActionState`:

```js
/*
  {
    actionState1: boolean;
    actionState2: boolean;
  }
*/
type ActionModelState {
  [key in keyof Action as `${typeof ActionState[key]}`]: boolean // all booleans but I need the keys to be restricted 
}

// throwing:
// Type 'key' cannot be used to index type '{ action1: "actionState1"; action2: "actionState2"; }'.
```

with which I'll extend my base type:

```js
type BaseAction = {
  id: number;
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
};
```

to form:

```js
type EnrichedAction = BaseAction & ActionModelState;
```

to end up with:

```js
const enrichedAction: EnrichedAction = {
  id: 123,
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar',
  actionState1: true,
  actionState2: false,
}
```

How can I define `ActionModelState` when I clearly know the members of `Action` as well as `ActionState`? The compiler complains that:

> Type 'key' cannot be used to index type '{ action1: "actionState1"; action2: "actionState2"; }'

but I figure `typeof key === keyof Action`. What am I doing wrong?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsRQN4CgpQIaKogCMUAvFAOQHJrGUA0O+haATOVTUW5VgL4BuLFgD0AKmYAVFFABGwfHIA2ihLLABnNQAtg2-JqgA3PMrD6GUECgRQAVlrsIAngAd9WcaKxw0mu3haEABlBDwERQpsXABtIKIAOm46AF0ALi5WUPDI+kMoPxAApjiEtGTstgys4LCI4F4CopKBYSxXDygAITxtcvRo5iQAE0zwCAUAJ2FcADMUFEyAqaQQAHNZ+Twp5YRVjeEhEQlmGNwWOtzgYky5RdU8EC3cFJyGtjuH4Cet-i8fJ1FAMALIoEbAZT1SKcc6xADWwBcUDWUERLhQc1g2QKAAMACQYIGY7FXBoIpGpfi4mr3FCPEACERAqAAURAqzgehGA04vX6OIAZKSiGCIVDru0WnZQJzuQNMuy5cAeTihrhRpliGwAMylKALJZUQ2MZhyHaZSjmqam17ZaE3TL7Cz6t4Oz4GszaJj-IA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just don't need `keyof Action` here at all; the type `Action` is already the union of those string values. So you want `key in Action`, not `key in keyof Action`.

```
type ActionModelState = {
  [key in Action as `${typeof ActionState[key]}`]: boolean
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsRQN4CgpQIaKogCMUAvFAOQHJrGUA0O+haATOVTUW5VgL4BuLFgD0AKmYAVFFABGwfHIA2ihLLABnNQAtg2-JqgA3PMrD6GUECgRQAVlrsIAngAd9WcaKxw0mu3haEABlBDwERQpsXABtIKIAOm46AF0ALi5WUPDI+kMoPxAApjiEtGTstgys4LCI4F4CopKBYSxXDygAITxtcvRo5iQAE0zwCAUAJ2FcADMUFEyAqaQQAHNZ+Twp5YRVjeEhEQlmGNwWOtzgYky5RdU8EC3cFJyGtjuH4Cet-i8fJ1FAMALIoEbAZT1SKcc6xADWwBcUDWsGyBQABgASDBAlBzNFXBoIpGpfgYmr3FCPEACERAqAAURAqzgehGA04vX66IAZISiGCIVDru0WnZQKz2QNMsypcAOeihrhRpliGwAMylKALJZUXWMZhyHaZSjGqaG17ZaE3TL7Czat42z46szaJj-IA)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, instead of trying to tame `keyof`, I can use a [`ValueOf` helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49286056/8160318) -- [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsRQN4CgpQIaKogCMUAvFAOQHJrGUA0O%20haATOVTUW5VgL4BuLFjhoAzglisQAZQR4EwTtlwBteLRAA6bnQC6ALi4z5i4PXzioYkJKbrNRXTLZGTWs0t5WbEhExCIggAngAOygBCeOLATmgqzEgAJsbgEABGwABOwrgAZigoxpLZSCAA5nlQGXjZJQhllcJBWMAAHmEo2VKhEVAAangANmDAAPL5ADwAKgB8nDNqANbAISj5UDP6wlh9yvEgALIoycDDXsoUqlAra1DlgyNjk1P7G9KeCkpz7hlFw2AeBALWC4WUAFEQGU4AALYDJQ6caKxJEAMk%20RBOZwu32Au1skigoBh8MRMmMUNJCKR1ySqSgxDYAGYHFBCsUqBzGMxavUqHyebg9HI8cRjI0xmyRZc2MZ8iNYgIsEA).

```js
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

type ActionModelState = {
  [key in ValueOf<typeof ActionState>]: boolean;
}
```

I still wonder whether I can use template literals in some shape or form...