# Ensure the Uniqueness of Literal Values in a Record Type

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

given the following code

```
const VALUES = {
    field1: "fieldA",
    field2: "fieldB",
} as const


export type RecToDU<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K]
}[keyof T]

type VALUESLiterals = RecToDU<typeof VALUES>
```

This yields correctly

```
type VALUESLiterals = "fieldA" | "fieldB"
```

Now I want to check that the literal values in my type are all unique such that

```
const VALUE = {
    field1: "fieldA",
    field2: "fieldB",
    field3: "fieldA" // "fieldA" is again a literal value
} as const

type VALUESLiterals = RecToDU<typeof VALUES>
```

will now yield `never` as a result instead of

```
type VALUESLiterals = "fieldA" | "fieldB"
```

as `field3` als contains the literal value `fieldA` which is already defined by `field1`. So if there are dublicate literal values the whole type should be `never`

Comment: The second example also yields "fieldA" | "fieldB" not `never` . 
Do you want it to yield `never` ?  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAagQQDIFUCiBlGBeGBvAKBmJgDMBLAUwBsATARgC4YAiCm2hFgGiJPboAmZmyp0AQjwIBfGAEMIMUJCgE1lAB4AHEACdYUAJ5bKMAEqVgAFRAARFAB4rAPhz4+xANoBpGOTAwANaUhiCkMFYAusxWPpEynsGh4VFqRibwyOgYSORQlLpy1Iq4FtZ2jumUYZmomM5qasrQteiCboQkZGIMIgKcUl39wqz9krxDPQDMfT1cMAD0C6NzLH6KcgDmcv7yMNR5BUUwAG5FAK6UMvKKzaoEVa2YufmFxe2lljb2DlU1iHVBA0CEsYI8AdkXkdim5RBx5gAfFYcSRAA

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir yes exactly. The type should be `never`

Comment: do you want to forbid unique values?

Comment: @captain-yossarian I edited my question. Hopefully it is clearer now

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NnXg6W) meet your needs?  Try it out on other use cases you care about; what happens if some of the properties are optional, or unions, or there's a string indexer?  If it works for your use cases I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the question to demonstrate a use case that the code here doesn't satisfy.

Comment: @jcalz yup exactly what I was looking for! POut into the answer

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/WyOXbN ?

Comment: @jcalz 's version is much cleaner than mine. I did not have a chance :D

Comment: As I have you all here now there is a tiny little question I have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70038878/how-to-build-a-unique-record-type-reverser
<duck away> ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `T` has no duplicate property values types, then you want `RecToDU<T>` to be the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all its property value types; otherwise you want it to be `never`.  The union of all the property value types of `T` can be computed simply by [indexing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into `T` with [the union of its keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator): `T[keyof T]`
([see this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript))
.

So you will want `RecToDU<T>` to be a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) of the form `type RecToDU<T> = XXX extends YYY ? T[keyof T] : never` or perhaps `type RecToDU<T> = XXX extends YYY ? never : T[keyof T]`.  So what will we do for `XXX` and `YYY`?

Here's one approach:

```
type RecToDU<T> = unknown extends {
   [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Omit<T, K>[Exclude<keyof T, K>] ? unknown : never
}[keyof T] ? never : T[keyof T]
```

Let's examine this bit:

```
{ [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Omit<T, K>[Exclude<keyof T, K>] ? unknown : never }
```

What we're doing is [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over each property key `K` in the keys of `T`, and for each property value `T[K]` we are comparing it to `Omit<T, K>[Exclude<keyof T, K>]`. [The `Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) produces a type that looks like `T` but with the `K` property removed; and [the `Exclude<X, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) produces a type which filters out `K` from any members of the union in `X`.  So `Omit<T, K>[Exclude<keyof T, K>]` is the union of all the property value types in `T` *except* for the property at key `K`.

For example, if `T` is `{a: 0, b: 1, c: 2}` and `K` is `"a"`, then `T[K]` is `0`. `Omit<T, K>` is `{b: 1, c: 2}`, and `Exclude<keyof T, K>` is `"b" | "c"`, and so `Omit<T, K>[Exclude<keyof T, K>]` is `1 | 2`.  And so in `T[K] extends Omit<T, K>[Exclude<keyof T, K>] ? ...` we are comparing `0 extends 1 | 2 ? ...` .  This is false, but would become true if `c` had a value of type `0` instead of `2`.

So if `T[K] extends Omit<T, K>[Exclude<keyof T, K>]`, it means that the property value at `K` is duplicated in some other property also.  Otherwise, it means that the property value at `K` is unique.  Note that the rest of that conditional type is `? unknown : never`, which means that for duplicate properties we produce [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) (the "top type" which absorbs all other types in unions), and for unique properties we produce [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) (the "bottom type" which is absorbed *into* all other types in unions).  Again with `T` being `{a: 0, b: 1, c: 2}`, we would produce `{a: never, b: never, c: never}`, but for `T` being `{a: 0, b: 1, c: 0}`, we would produce `{a: unknown, b: never, c: unknown}`.

Now let's examine

```
{ [K in keyof T]-?: 
  T[K] extends Omit<T, K>[Exclude<keyof T, K>] ? unknown : never 
}[keyof T]
```

which is the same as before, but we're indexing into it with `keyof T`.  So we're taking the mapped type and getting the union of its values.  For `{a: 0, b: 1, c: 2}` this is `never | never | never` which is just `never`.  But for `{a: 0, b: 1, c: 0}` this is `unknown | never | unknown` which is `unknown`.  Since `unknown` absorbs all other types in unions, and `never` is absorbed into all other types in unions, the only way `never` can come out of this is if every single property is unique.  If even one property value is a duplicate (uh, I guess there has to be at least two of these, maybe? maybe not, if one of these is a supertype of the other... ugh, never mind), then `unknown` comes out.

So we have a conditional type that evaluates to `unknown` if any properties are duplicated, and `never` if they are all unique. Hence:

```
type RecToDU<T> = unknown extends {
   [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Omit<T, K>[Exclude<keyof T, K>] ? unknown : never
}[keyof T] ? never : T[keyof T]
```

since `unknown extends XXX` is only true when `XXX` is itself `unknown`, this check is only true if `T` has duplicate properties, and false if `T` has all unique properties.  For duplicate properties we return `never`, and for unique ones we return `T[keyof T]`.

---

Whew, let's see if it works:

```
const VALUES = {
   field1: "fieldA",
   field2: "fieldB",
   field3: "fieldC"
} as const

type VALUESLiterals = RecToDU<typeof VALUES>
// type VALUESLiterals = "fieldA" | "fieldB" | "fieldC"
```

okay, and then:

```
const VALUES = {
   field1: "fieldA",
   field2: "fieldB",
   field3: "fieldA"
} as const

type VALUESLiterals = RecToDU<typeof VALUES>
// type VALUESLiterals = never
```

Looks good!

---

Note that the above implementation of `RecToDU<T>` was only tested with object types containing non-[optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) properties without [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) and whose property values are single [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) and not unions or intersections of other types.  If these conditionals are altered, then `RecToDu<T>` as implemented above might produce some weird or undesirable results.  So be careful to test against use cases you care about, and alter the definition accordingly if necessary.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGAVA9gEQKoB5ED4oF4oBXAOwGsTkB3EqCAD2AhIBMBnKAbwCgo+BtANJQAlrTIQQyAGZREAXQC0AfgBccofLqNm7KAHkAtiODYANFEE5+AUXrwANkRYRMEqbMQWrW5cXKUNFDqJBAAbhAATtwAvvzuMnK+UKERkcEaCZ7y3NwkAIaGEGxg+fDQABpcvHzwyCRswFAAagCCADLoNgDKBNV8A1DSIhAOLACM6gBEw6MsrVNmNYOzYwBM06ssAEKLywNbAMybI2MAwlPLMVD5HHUNwLkDoJAtHV3d7SZR+Q4chHAkGgsC8IIk2p0ejhlgB6GFQUFvSGfb6RX7-KAzU7zKZQAA+mK2u3xhOxF1ieUKxVK5SgAE1+rV6o0kR8+jxBnwtpNSXMFktOUNsRteWNdgLOUcTnzLgNrrcoPdGk8+IiIR8vkw0X8+oCUBhMKDwe8obD4WqTSitei+qkorEgA)

Comment: I have a couple of questions:
1. I tried `{ ... } extends unknown ? .. : ..` , but that doesnt work, is there a reason `unknown` needs to come first? Is it the union distribution?
2. If we're excluding `K` from the keys, then we shouldn't need to omit it too right? I tried it in a quick test and it worked, but I may be missing another scenario.