# Get string literal types from Array of objects

Tags: typescript, typeof, union-types, keyof

So from:

```
export interface Category{
  val: string;
  icon: string
}
const categoryArray: Category[] = [
  {
    val: 'business',
    icon: 'store'
  },
  {
    val: 'media',
    icon: 'video'
  },
  {
    val: 'people',
    icon: 'account'
  },

  ...
```

I'd like to get a Union type back like this:

```
'business' | 'media' | 'people' ...
```

I don't know what kind of syntax or helpers there are for this, maybe none at all. I realise this way might be backwards, and should perhaps use an Enum, but before that, I want to know it it's possible.

Some fictional examples of what I'd like to do, but the solution I expect to be more complex

```
type Cats = keysof[] categoryArray 'val'  
type Cats = valuesof categoryArray 'val'
```

The following is close, but returns `string`:

```
export type CatsValType = typeof categories[number]['val']
```

Or the following; instead of the types I need the string literals

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type KeyTypes = ValueOf<typeof categories[number]> // Returns: `string`
```

There are similar questions like: [Is there a `valueof` similar to `keyof` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript) but they don't assume an array of objects.

And the example here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html is similar, but I don't want to return the type, but the value of the fields, so I get a Union type back.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it **if**:

- The values in the array don't change at runtime (since type information is a compile-time-only thing with TypeScript); and
- You tell TypeScript that they values won't change by using `as const`; and

2. You *don't* give the `categoryArray` constant the type `Category[]`, because if you do the result would just be `string` (because `Category["val"]`'s type is `string`) rather than the string literal union type you want.

Here's an example ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYU1QHNoBPOAbwCg44A3TAGwC44BnGKZYgblsTYISNp25Ji1AL7UhSTnGxFgpKGQCCUKJgoBeOAG0BNOnUas4AcgBGAV3bJg7dpYA0AugjltLnaMEsBKXc6E1NzHwBbYAATBEw3D0FhH3oEGOAIQLpg4ySIqzBMsCYAkNMvFKscIVsUbLhcgF04THZFYU5+ahgyIrgAFQALYAA1ZltgAFUkBGE4fQAKXqKIdEVlVQ0tHQBKAyRbSOs0JoMAInNzpv4AelvTAD0AfiA)):

```
export interface Category{
  val: string;
  icon: string
}
const categoryArray = [
  {
    val: 'business',
    icon: 'store'
  },
  {
    val: 'media',
    icon: 'video'
  },
  {
    val: 'people',
    icon: 'account'
  },
] as const;

type TheValueUnion = (typeof categoryArray)[number]["val"];
//   ^? −− "business" | "media" | "people"
```

The key bits there are the `as const` and `type TheValueUnion = (typeof categoryArray)[number]["val"];`, which breaks down like this:

1. `typeof categoryArray` gets the type of `categoryArray` (the inferred type, since we didn't assign a specific one).
2. `[number]` to access the union of types indexed by number on the type of `categoryArray`.
3. `["val"]` to access the union of types for the `val` property on the union from #2, which is the string literal type you want: `"business" | "media" | "people"`.

Comment: Thanks, that almost worked for me, now the problem is that any 'optional' property on the `Category` becomes readonly and mandatory. I didn't include any optional in the example, but let's say I have a `disabled?: boolean;` there, it will error: `Property 'disabled' does not exist on type '{ readonly val: "art"; readonly... etc.`

Comment: @TrySpace - That's odd, [I don't get that](https://tsplay.dev/wR9Y1W) and I'm not sure where that error would come up, we're not doing anything to `Category` above. Can you update that playground example to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYU1QHNoBPOAbwCg44A3TAGwC44BnGKZYgblsTYISNp25I+AgCYJ2mAEZNgUgPxt5ECEsxJ+AX2pCknONiLBSUMgEEoUTBQC8cANoCadOo1ZwA5PIBXdmRgdnZfABoBOgQjNl9OaGBI6LgZOUVlNi4A4AE9KLoPT294gFtlBEwUz0FhePoEKWAIGs98wqpU0r8wFrAlNpi4vxwhAJRfDuoAXThMdlNhTn5qGDI+uAAVAAtgADVmXIBVJARhOGcACnW+iHRTc0sbOwcAShckALL5NBmXABE3gBM34AHowZ4AHoqaiGZZaYAAOiYEGIVzMJHItnsZCR6QUSikbyAA

Comment: @TrySpace - You're trying to use `disabled` on the **array**. It's not on the array, it's on array **elements**.

Comment: You're right, This is what I meant: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYU1QHNoBPOAbwCg44A3TAGwC44BnGKZYgblsTYISNp25I+AgCYJ2mAEZNgUgPxt5ECEsxJ+AX2pCknONiLBSUMgEEoUTBQC8cANoCadOo1ZwA5PIBXdmRgdnZfABoBOgQjNl9OaGBI6LgZOUVlNi4A4AE9KLoPT294gFtlBEwUz0FhePoEKWAIGs98wqpU0r8wFrAlNpi4vxwhAJRfDuoAXThMdlNhTn5qGDI+uAAVAAtgADVmXIBVJARhOGcACnW+iHRTc0sbOwcAShckALL5NBmXABE3gBM34AHowZ4AHoqaiGZZaYAAOiYEGIVzMJHItnsZBcAEYZkj0golFI3kA  I cannot conditionally use the `disabled` property, unless it is certainly defined in the read-only object.

Comment: While technically the `disabled` prop doesn't exists, I need to conditionally check the presence of the `disabled` prop. As if I had `categoryArray: Category[] = ...` defined, but I can't use both that AND TheValueUnion...

Comment: @TrySpace - You could always do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPxEeW). :-) (You could even do a runtime validation check to make sure the type assertion isn't wrong as the code changes over time.)