# Typescript type meaning "any one of the fields of this interface"

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a situation like this:

```js
interface Foo {
  a: { name: string };
  b: { x: number; y: number };
}

const obj: Foo = createFoo();
const member = obj[Math.random() > 0.5 ? "a" : "b"];
```

Here, TypeScript correctly infers that the type of `member` should be `{ name: string } | { x: number; y: number }`. But, say I want to do something like this:

```js
handleFooMember(member);

function handleFooMember(member: /* what type do I put here? */) {
  if ("name" in member) {
    console.log(member.name);
  } else {
    console.log(member.x, member.y);
  }
}
```

How do I type that function so that the `member` argument could be any field of `Foo`? Obviously, I could hard-code that union type (`{ name: string } | { x: number; y: number }`). But if `Foo` has a lot of complex fields or I might add more fields later on, that's not ideal.

Is there a typescript way to express the idea of "Any of the field of this type"? Something like `Union<Members<Foo>>`?

Comment: You're looking for `Foo[keyof Foo]`, using [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49285864/2887218

Comment: @jcalz Thanks I think you're right. I'll mark as duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical approach is:

```
function handleFooMember(member: Foo[keyof Foo]) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it. Thanks. I searched all over for this but couldn't find the documentation for it