# Catch all types of an interrface keys

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I catch all types of an interface keys?

I have below object:

```js
interface WorkingTime {
  id?: number;
  openTime: number;
  closeTime: number;
  type?: string;
  status: 0 | 1 | 2;
  day: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7;
  clinicId?: number;
  clinicStaffId?: number;
}
```

Now I want set a type which that get all types of the interface and the result will be as below:

```js
type X = string | number | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7;
```

Thanks for your participating to answer my question

Comment: Note that the type of `id` is `number | undefined` unless you have compiler options to show otherwise, so you'd get `undefined` in there also.  And if you write `type X = string | number | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7;` you will see that reduced to `type X = string | number`;  So the [obvious way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49285864/2887218) will give you just `string | number | undefined`.  What do you actually need this for?

Answer (score 1):

```
type X = Required<WorkingTime>[keyof WorkingTime];
```

Each number(`0, 1, 2, ...`) is extended from number, so `X` cannot be `string | number | 0 | 1 | 2 ...` but should be `string | number`