# Union of Properties' Types

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript type like

```
type MyType =
{
    fooProp: Foo;
    barProp: Bar;
    bazProp: Baz;
};
```

How can I define a type which is the union of the type's properties' types, so I can have a type

```
Foo | Bar | Baz
```

?

Comment: `MyType[keyof MyType]`

Comment: That's not an intersection. It's a union.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a \`valueof\` similar to \`keyof\` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript)