# Merge value types of tuple of objects in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, typing

I have a set of objects, each with its own properties:

```js
const a = { a1 : 1, a2 : 2 } as const
const b = { b1 : `1`, b2 : `2` } as const
```

The function `f` takes all these objects as a typed tuple:

```js
function f<
    T extends { [key : string] : any }[]
> (
    ...t : [...{ [i in keyof T] : T[i] }]
) {
    // todo
}

f(a, b)
```

The goal is to return any property of any of these objects.
In this case, the expected result should be `1 | 2 | "1" | "2"`.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to properly describe the return type.

I have tried `T[number][keyof T[number]]` but it have failed, probably due to possible differences in indexes for `T` and `keyof T`.

Then I wrote a wrapper for it:

```js
type PropertyOf<T extends { [key : string] : any }> = T[keyof T]
```

And specify the return type of `f` as `PropertyOf<T[number]>`. But it still doesn't work.

Despite `PropertyOf` returns expected `1 | 2` for `PropertyOf<{ a1 : 1, a2 : 2 }>`, when used as `PropertyOf<T[number]>` in `f` the function return type is `never`.

What is the reason and how to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this approach:

```
declare function f<T extends object[]>(
    ...t: T
): { [I in keyof T]: T[I][keyof T[I]] }[number]
```

- note that `object` is often more forgiving for callers than `{ [key : string] : any }` because the latter's index signature prevents you from passing in values of `interface` types; see [ms/TS#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300).
- note that your input type `[...{ [i in keyof T] : T[i] }]` is indistinguishable from `T` for a rest parameter.

But importantly, we are [mapping over the `T` tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) and computing your `PropertyOf<T>` type (also called `ValueOf<T>` according to [Is there a `valueof` similar to `keyof` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49285864/2887218) ) for each tuple element, then [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the resulting tuple with `number`, resulting in a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the types in that tuple.

Let's test it out:

```
const a = { a1: 1, a2: 2 } as const
const b = { b1: `1`, b2: `2` } as const

const ret = f(a, b);
// const ret: 1 | 2 | "1" | "2"
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAmFMGMBsEMCdwAIBmBXAdpALgSwPYaoA8AKkuAB7bgagDOS+ARgFZTYDaAugHwAUwJMKQA6cdgBcSUsACU0gN5JOASSS4iAa3ABPfChndppNd0479h06u7ckAX04Y0AW2bh43EJEL1sSLBIALxIyrAAjNIRADSBAEzS8Y6BjL4Y-sDp-kjMIWG5UUgABhHFccyJJfHFKbBpftg+jUiIAaEo-LAVcgDcwAD0A0jZAW3RSAA+SMnTAEQRc1NIc-FzwEA)

Answer (score 1):

We can use the following as the return type for `f`.

```
function f<
    T extends { [key : string] : any }[]
> (...t : [...{ [i in keyof T] : T[i] }])
  : T[number] extends Record<string, infer U> ? U : never 
{
   return {} as any
}

const result = f(a, b)
//    ^? const result: 1 | 2 | "1" | "2"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3vAjDAXDdAaeAJmxmIF94IZRIoAoG6GAIyVRcxwAN0uDni3QlxgU4VRvToAzAK5hgUAJbgY0gDx0Y2mABUYAUwAeUA2AAmVNAG0A1gYCeJaACclYAOYBdEnDBOyay86AD4YAAoAOmjYHGtoyJslGHcYewcQaT0fHF1rJR8yLwBKLRI8sFkAW2YDFx9jUwsqACUDUBdzdVd3DwJ3aTqYAFUwgH4RkjADADchuhQymBcDKFkXMFQxKj8HOjI6BnAmFYhZABtYZGlwuH5SgHoHnRgAPTGgA)

---

The `keyof` operator does not work here because it only returns shared properties when used on object unions. Both objects don't share any properties, so `keyof` evaluates to `never`.