# Infer property type from object list type

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript type `Items`, and it is used for an object list like this:

```
const items: Items = {
 '1': { id: '1', name: 'first' },
 '2': { id: '2', name: 'second' },
}
```

I want to derive the type `Item` from `Items`, so that this is valid:

```
const getItem = (items: Items, key: string): Item => {
  return items[key];
}
```

How can I derive `Item` from `Items`?

Comment: Can you show `Item` / `Items` class definitions?

Comment: Without seeing the type definition of `Items` it's going to be difficult to provide a useful answer. Regardless, I would strongly suggest having an explicit type `Item` for the map values rather than trying to derive it from the map type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know how the type `Items` is defined so I used `typeof items`:

```
type Item = typeof items[keyof typeof items];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do the opposite: derivate `Items` from `Item` to proceed from simple to complex. This is IMHO a cleaner way to design things.

```
interface Item {
    id: string;
    key: string;
}
type Items = {[key : string] : Item};
```

Anyway, if you can't change the way you define them, you can try to implement a `valueof` that would be a  `keyof` analogous.

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
```

Then you would just use it this way:

```
type Item =  ValueOf<Items>;
```

(See a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49286056/1153988))

But if you define `Items` this way or something similar (you didn't mention it in your question)...

```
type Items = {
    '1': {
        id: string;
        name: string;
    };
    '2': {
        id: string;
        name: string;
    };
}
```

...You get `Item` the could be redefined as

```
type Item = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
} | {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}
```

...which is a bit dumb IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

```
  type Item = { id: string; name: string };
  type Items = Record<string, Item>;
  const items: Items = {
    '1': { id: '1', name: 'first' },
    '2': { id: '2', name: 'second' },
  };
  type IKey = keyof typeof items;

  const getItem = (items: Items, key: IKey): Item => {
    return items[key];
  };
```

OR

**Following the template of `items` object**

```
  type IKey = keyof typeof items;
  type Item = typeof items[IKey];

  const getItem = (items: Items, key: IKey): Item => {
    return items[key];
  };
```