# Type like `Record<string, keyof T>` that guarantees each key in `keyof T` is used?

Tags: typescript, types, mapped-types, typesafe

I make a simple example just to show a problem. There it is

```
class Person{
    public Name: string = '';
    public Age: number = 0;
}

class Some {
    public StringToKey: Record<string, keyof Person> = {
        "N": "Name",
        "A": "Age"
    }
    public KeyToVal: {[Key in keyof Person]: (value:string)=>Person[Key]} = {
        Name: (value: string) => {return value;},
        Age: (value: string) => {return Number(value);}
    }
}
```

All looks good and compile. If i add new property to Person, i want to get 2 errors: for `StringToKey` and `KeyToVal`, but i only have error in `KeyToVal` situation.

So, for `StringToKey` declaration i can't be sure that i will get error if something will be changed in `Person` class, which is bad for me.

Is there any magic in type declaration i could do to get error in `StringToKey` declaration when `Person` class has been changed?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wg8E9N) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz maybe my example was bad, what if i have more difference in those types, i will change Some class slightly

Comment: @jcalz you can edit my question if it really has nothing to do with type safety, i didn't know how to better phrase the problem. KeyToString is mentioned by me as example of  behaviour that i expect, when some new property will be added to Person class (there will be error) 
I wanna know is there some way to get same behaviour for StringToKey case?

Comment: That's ①&②, did you look at ③? [This playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WYQArW) shows a way of initializing `StringToKey` so that it complains if you're missing one.

Comment: @jcalz sorry for my carelessness, this looks like exactly what i need! But i really newbie in ts mapped types, so i don't understand your solution, could you explain it?

Comment: Yes I'll write up an answer explaining when I get a chance.

Comment: @jcalz is there a way to upgrade your solution to use any class, not only Person? i mean make it more generic?? if so, it will be 10 out of 10!!

Comment: Maybe, but I'm in the middle of writing up the answer you already agreed was sufficient.  I am not going to worry about that until after the answer, and if I can easily "upgrade" it I will do so in a comment, which will probably be deleted later since followup questions are out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jcalz ok, you've already saved my day, so i will try to understand your solution and make it more generic by myself)

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/Wk84jw) is how I might generalize it.  Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript really doesn't have a way to represent an "exhaustive" type that ensures that each member of some [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) is known to be present as a property value. So no specific type like `type ExhaustivePersonKeyRecord = ExhaustiveRecord<string, keyof T>` exists, since there's no way to implement `ExhaustiveRecord` directly.

---

Instead the best we can do is write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `ExhaustivePersonKeyRecord<T>` that acts as a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on `T` so that `T extends ExhaustivePersonKeyRecord<T>` if and only if `T` has a property value for every key of `Person`.

Once we have that, we'd write a generic helper identity function that uses such a type, like this:

```
function exhaustivePersonKeyRecord<T extends Record<keyof T, keyof Person>>(
  t: ExhaustivePersonKeyRecord<T>
) { return t }
```

That will make it so that `exhaustivePersonKeyRecord({a: "Name", b: "Age"})` will succeed but `exhaustivePersonKeyRecord({a: "Name"})` will fail.

---

All we have to do is define an appropriate `ExhaustivePersonKeyRecord<T>` type. Here's one possible way to do it:

```
declare const __some_property__: unique symbol;
type ExhaustivePersonKeyRecord<T> = T & (keyof Person extends T[keyof T] ? unknown :
  { [__some_property__]: Exclude<keyof Person, T[keyof T]> }
)
```

That's `T` [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that compares `keyof Person` to `T[keyof T]`.  The type `T[keyof T]` is the union of all property types included in `T` (as discussed in [Is there a `valueof` similar to `keyof` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49285864/2887218) ).  If `keyof Person extends T[keyof T]` it means that `T[keyof T]` is wider than `keyof Person` and thus contains every member.  That's what you want.

If that check is true and you used all the keys of `Person` in the properties of `T`, then the conditional type evaluates to [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) and `T & unknown` is just `T`.  And `T extends T`, so it will succeed.

If that check is false, and you missed some key or keys of `Person`, then the conditional type evaluates to `{ [__some_property__]: Exclude<keyof Person, T[keyof T]> }`.  This is an object type with the key of type `__some_property__` (a fake [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) type I declared just to have some "key" to say we missed) and a value of type `Exclude<keyof Person, T[keyof T]>`, using [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) to determine the missing keys.  If `T` is, say, `{a: "Name"}`, then `Exclude<keyof Person, T[keyof T]>` will be `"Age"`, and the whole type will evaluate to `{a: "Name"} & {[__some_property__]: "Age"}`, and so `T extends ExhaustivePersonKeyRecord<T>` will be false, and it will fail.

---

Let's test it out:

```
class Some {
  public StringToKey = exhaustivePersonKeyRecord({
    "N": "Name",
    "A": "Age",
  }); // okay
}
```

That works until we augment `Person`:

```
class Person {
  public Name: string = '';
  public Age: number = 0;
  public Height: number = 0; // <-- do this
}
```

Then we get the desired error:

```
class Some {
  public StringToKey = exhaustivePersonKeyRecord({
    "N": "Name",
    "A": "Age"
  }); // error
}
//  Property '[__some_property__]' is missing in type '{ N: "Name"; A: "Age"; }'
// but required in type '{ [__some_property__]: "Height"; }'.
```

which hopefully gives us enough information to fix it:

```
class Some {
  public StringToKey = exhaustivePersonKeyRecord({
    "N": "Name",
    "A": "Age",
    "H": "Height"
  }); // okay
}
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEAKBTATlA9gO1gb2LWADgK4BGYAliLAHIQC2iAXLFAC7LkYDmsAvLAHIBAbjyFSFKgEEuTWBiJ0SKPrAAMo-MTKVYACUTkuAC1bMFSlfw3AAvsGAATROAjJEsEJjawA+r-QGXwJkNAIUVgBPf2YiDHIARyIPKEilNDBRKPDYAFEAD2MIIjZyADdEJFRMAGlESIAlFzRkRwAeABUAPlUO2AAyWAAKAGt6tAAzBBR0LER81kQMRzgOgG0xyMnYDoBdWAB+WDiRjDQAdyxGMWxYNf9AxGDQ8OQo-13mAvAiZzbN7ZVWYAGh2G3GUz2PXsAEoHBM4iBWORMLB5kUSsiKkDavUml5Wp00QslitYPiWu0AZDQdTptUMF0ukMxGY8oViqVsTNcY1moTusAYThYO5WERkFhWLB7KBIDBYABlNAMHBibSSJXsThcDpoOqRVTozlYyo8jAGimtIa4fD4ABE1HtzEd9EQ9uBYgdUmdsHtMndnrtfr0vvtBiMpntYlsMOEsAA9AnYGgRhBInYHK4FQB5VjGFS28Q6KiK7XcPUGo0czHlM0My38xw2r1+p0u2gMD2t-1hgPR-Cx+NJtHIULITMjhAvCKGgT3AIqp4hMKzj4CWDkOB0LdQHWbqWRHICW7UDtu+3xqQu-vx2wCYAjkhEaXuJLkdyOA+wbIeE93B4l2eVc3miXxPhDQwTFYS8ZQEAA6IYACYAGYABYAFY4QcHDgCAA)

Comment: @MikHail just a follow-up of this answer with the generic support instead of `Person`. [playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nn8x6W). jcalz, you can include this to your answer if you wish so

Comment: I did it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/Wk84jw) too... I don't want to expand the scope here if I don't have to