# Extract from a union of interface with a type field where the type field is an enum union

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I was developing a typescript project where I came across a situation that I'd like to get type inference and completion for the second argument `data` of a function which depends on the first argument `type` of the function.

Here is the example type

```js
enum MessageType {
  FOO = "FOO",
  BAR = "BAR",
  BAZ = "BAZ",
}

interface DataFoo {
  type: MessageType.FOO
  payload: string
}

interface DataBarOrBaz {
  type: MessageType.BAR | MessageType.BAZ
  name: string
  age: number
}

type Data = DataFoo | DataBarOrBaz
```

This is the function I am developing and I would like to have autocomplete for the `data` parameter

```js
function emit<T extends MessageType>(type: T, data: ???) {}
```

The expected result is like this

```js
emit(MessageType.FOO, {
  payload: "hello world"
  // with autocomplete for payload in DataFoo
})

emit(MessageType.BAR, {
  name: "hello"
  age: 18
  // with autocomplete for name and age in DataBarOrBaz
})

emit(MessageType.BAZ, { 
  name: "hello",
  age: 18
  // with autocomplete for name and age in DataBarOrBaz
})
```

However when I try to achieve the intended result with the `Extract` utility type in typescript, it doesn't work for the interfaces that the `type` field is a union of `MessageType`

```js
function emit<T extends MessageType>(type: T, data: Omit<Extract<Data, {type: T}>, "type">) {}
```

```js
emit(MessageType.FOO, { // the type for data becomes Omit<DataFoo, "type">
  payload: "hello world" 
  // works as intended
})

emit(MessageType.BAR, { // the type for data becomes Omit<never, "type">
// expecting the type to be Omit<DataBarOrBaz, "type">
})

emit(MessageType.BAZ, { // the type for data becomes Omit<never, "type">
// expecting the type to be Omit<DataBarOrBaz, "type">
})
```

Is there any way to achieve the goal using typescript v5?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAssDO8CGBzYAVAngB2FA3gFBRQBiA8uVALxQBEF5dANMVAEICCASjfV9xZsuALT51RQgL6FCASxAAXYACcAZkgDGeACJJFSUgHsjBNopzAAXLATI0WXADpGbbEkwAbI0gAmN+EUVBRRCGXklVQ1tKD0DdiQVchUEgC8zEgtcGzhEVAxLJwEoAB9bPIdC0TYQJAhrKEDgkFCSfJtwCAAjVTDZLN19JD44wxNS2KGEpJSkVNk1MBBNRTkjEChgCDlFAB50TYAPZRBfeHL7AtwAPgAKAZt0ZihfIZtybb2AUWOVLT3Rs98A8oOgpNdnnQBnRrgBKAjhLY7W65S6OYAuShAtwebx+Gx0AAWwE83igAHcjCpPL46GFYbIkYoUXZ8uiijwgVAAPTcqCKYn8yxQNRUl5DKA9TRGernD47XYgYAAN1UkOh10IvKOuBWIX5goG-NMPSg8oBU0SyTS6ssMPpjM+LIqVwxoi52oFeCNopU4oMkuA0tlZs+ipVavoGq1fOAh11qxaBu9wsUJrw5t2o2m1rmttw9qksKAA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nda1Qm) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Similar approach: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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

Comment: @wonderflame, yes it is working! But I don't understand this line `K in Data as T extends K["type"]`. Can you explain more about it? Thanks.

Comment: sure, will do soon in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is actually correct, however, the problem is with `Extract`. To be more precise, the problem is with the way `Extract` checks whether `T` extends the other type:

```
/**
 * Extract from T those types that are assignable to U
 */
type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;
```

The problem in this condition is that `T` is a union in the case with `DataBarOrBaz`:

```
interface DataBarOrBaz {
  type: MessageType.BAR | MessageType.BAZ;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

So, when we actually pass `MessageType.BAZ` to the emit, we get this condition:

```
// false
type Case1 = MessageType.BAR | MessageType.BAZ extends MessageType.BAZ ? true : false
```

Which is obviously false, since the left part is less specific than the right part, which makes the right part of the condition a *subset* of the left, since it is more specific.

So, to fix the issue we should reverse the condition, to:

```
// true
type Case2 = MessageType.BAZ extends MessageType.BAR | MessageType.BAZ ? true : false
```

To achieve this, we will use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to map through every version of the message, and by using the [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) we are going to add the condition that was mentioned previosly. If the type matches the condition then we make key to be `message.type`, just to make the mapped type valid, since we can only use `string | number | symbol` as keys in the objects, though we won't actually need the keys, only values. In the value we will just omit `type` from the message:

```
type FindData<T extends MessageType> = {
  [K in Data as T extends K['type'] ? K['type'] : never]: Omit<K, 'type'>;
}
```

Testing:

```
// type Result = {
//     BAR: Omit<DataBarOrBaz, "type">;
//     BAZ: Omit<DataBarOrBaz, "type">;
// }
type Result = FindData<MessageType.BAR>
```

The values looks good and to extract them, we will use the `ValueOf` described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript):

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

type FindData<T extends MessageType> = ValueOf<{
  [K in Data as T extends K['type'] ? K['type'] : never]: Omit<K, 'type'>;
}>;

// type Result = {
//     name: string;
//     age: number;
// }
type Result = FindData<MessageType.BAR>;
```

Usage:

```
function emit<T extends MessageType>(type: T, data: FindData<T>) {}

emit(MessageType.FOO, {
  payload: 'hello world',
});

emit(MessageType.BAR, {
  name: 'hello',
  age: 18,
});

emit(MessageType.BAZ, {
  name: 'hello',
  age: 18,
});
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nda1Qm)