# Is it possible to split object into a union of its properties?

Tags: typescript

I have object [https://www.typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBGARgKzgXmAb2HXcA2AlrAFxwDaARAKIAeAhgLYAO+ApgIyUA0cNDLdgCZKAXW448UNjBiEIAcyhlMxahHqJ2AEzIwATgFc2vAG5t9UQpDKVTHAHRcAvhLxw2tA-RUdbPOCF-XgBmf2dgCOAYAE9mNgQUdDhY+LAAM0TkAG5gAHo8vAA9AH5ouITPeJAYNm1kzCJSOABBfX16GIAeWH15BQA+ZzgAHzhMaVl+5XG1DS06skQwMHZ6CDMLKxs4Xv7nYbHMT29fMj3FXiDdg37Q89vFA9yC4rLUhIBlVkIYLoAVDxeNgQbRQcbOAbJcgAazYMQycH+oiBtVB4PIIDI8nSFjgAGEOLwHCT9Gxmji8fihCiSgSOKMCUI4LYuNk4OV4nAyVBDPh4Gg4N8iH8kMgBi9CrhSpIgA):

```
const obj =
{
    list: ["Example1", "Example2"],
    settings: {isEnabled: true, version: "v1.1"},
    extra: {1: "", 2: "", 3: ""}
}
```

I want to split `obj` into a union of its properties: `{list: ...} | {settings: ...} | {extra: ...}`:

```
type obj = typeof obj;
type expected = {list: Array<string>} | {settings: {isEnabled: boolean, version: string}} | {extra: {1: string, 2: string, 3: string}};
```

Is this possible?

---

My attempts:

```
// this doesn't work, it's my attempt, how to introduce recursion here?
type Split<T extends {}> = [keyof T] extends [c: infer C1, ...rest: infer C2] ? C1 | C2 : "1"; 
type Split1<T extends {}> = [keyof T] extends (infer C1 | infer C2) ? {[C1]: any} | {[C2]: any} : "1"; 
type result = Split<obj>;
type result1 = Split1<obj>;
```

I know that somehow I need to introduce recursion with destructuring assignment, but can't figure out how.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAgRPw) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am i missing?

Comment: Better take a look at [this one](https://tsplay.dev/mpARzW). In the previous one I was removing readonlies and literals

Comment: @wonderflame okey second version is more approachable.

Comment: @wonderflame okey. Write this as answer, I will accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will need to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to generate a type which will have the following structure:

```
// Initial
{
 x: string
 y: number
}

// Result
{
 x: {x: string}
 y: {y: number}
}
```

After that, we can just take all values, which will generate a *union* that you want:

```
type Split<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]: { [P in K]: T[P] };
};
```

Testing:

```
// type Result = {
//     list: {
//         list: string[];
//     };
//     settings: {
//         settings: {
//             isEnabled: boolean;
//             version: string;
//         };
//     };
//     extra: {
//         extra: {
//             1: string;
//             2: string;
//             3: string;
//         };
//     };
// }
type Result = Split<typeof obj>;
```

Looks good, now by using `ValueOf` described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript), we will get all values:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

type Split<T extends object> = ValueOf<{
  [K in keyof T]: { [P in K]: T[P] };
}>;
```

Testing:

```
// type Result = {
//   list: string[];
// } | {
//   settings: {
//       isEnabled: boolean;
//       version: string;
//   };
// } | {
//   extra: {
//       1: string;
//       2: string;
//       3: string;
//   };
// }
type Result = Split<typeof obj>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGAbAltAFwwDaA5AKIAeAhgLYAOuApgIzkA0MVdTrAJnIBdTthgQWUKPjABzCCXQxClMLXisAJiSgAnAK4tuANxZ6I+cCXIm2AOg4wAvmJwtq+2kphsbXGAF-bgBmfxcxZwBuTEwoAE9GFhgPJOAoFi1UcQAfDDxCKBIAQT09WniAHmg9WTkAPhdc-MlpOsV81XVNTJJ4EBBWWjAomDMLKzASGrqXJpw85Q8vHz8JfTrRoPXa+VGwndnnFxi4xOSANVpcIwB5ADNKgBVGtCfSAGsWeJB7mCfhKcEkkYABlZj4KDPFKeFhgLQQOBIFjpV4wK43FgPSpYHCkADSKjAMC+Pz+AJ8pAACkSYPjhCR3lThCdMM56qcAPScmDA5IAJRYEAMuFgaCw3JwBWIh3kpEBmElx0Wip5OFaMnkHQlaqlOC6Gm0fQGQxGqr1UvGlmssrkMUlOGi5uVGHN7k85SUbotaxme29eu2frtAalB2D9t1TqVZxBguFotQYIhUL5vyRiA5mCAA)

Comment: `type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];` does the trick.