# How to reference the type of an enum using only a variable containing the enum

Tags: typescript, enums, typeof

A third-party library exports a variable containing an enum instead of the enum itself:

```
enum Size { S, M, L }
export const sizeType: typeof Size = Size;
```

In my own code, how can I declare that something has type `Size`?

```
import { sizeType } from '...';

interface Props {
    size: /* What goes here that's equivalent to 'Size'? */
}

const props: Props = { size: sizeType.S };
props.size = sizeType.L;
```

Here are some declarations I tried that don't work:

```
size: typeof sizeType;
// error: Type 'Size' is not assignable to type 'typeof Size'.

size: typeof sizeType['S'];
// error: Type 'Size.L' is not assignable to type 'Size.S'.

size: InstanceType<typeof sizeType>;
// error: Type `typeof Size' does not satisfy the constraint 'abstract new (...args: any) => any`.
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDA8xm) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame: I came up with the same solution, and was wondering whether there was a shorter alternative. But yes, that works.

Comment: The [shorter version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAyglgL2FA3gKCrANBqBZHTAGRwF801gAPABwHsAnAFygGM6QBnFzxYAFQCeNYAC4oTYcDoAzWHygBeeUgDcFSSKgA1AIYAbMMADyMgDz8AfEqj8A2gGtgg2bYC6FOCCbAGM3azIAAoMdDScqLi8SOJ6hibmmtJy0QJSlmjkaOxcLDSh4eIhYRHKKFCp4qlCIgB0MFCk6vkltak21VK1ROpAA). Should I write an answer then?

Comment: @wonderflame: Please write up both versions. I think some people may not want the extra type in one-off situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have access to the enum, the only option will be to get the type of the values of the enum by using the `sizeType`:

```
// typeof Size
type Case1 = typeof sizeType
// typeof Size
type Case2 = typeof Size
```

Now, by using the [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) let's get the type of every value in *union* format:

```
// Size
type Case3 = typeof sizeType[keyof typeof sizeType]
// Size
type Case4 = typeof Size[keyof typeof Size]
```

With the enums, the whole thing looks a bit weird and that's why I personally prefer to use [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) + the [satisfies](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html) operator on javascript object:

```
const SIZE =  {
  S :0,
  M: 1,
  L: 2,
} as const satisfies Record<string, number>
```

Anyway, moving back to the problem, let's test the type that we got in the last cases:

```
const case3A: Case3 = Size.S
const case3B: Case3 = 'error' // error

const case4A: Case4 = Size.S
const case4B: Case4 = 'error' // error
```

Looks good!

Usage:

```
interface Props {
  size: typeof sizeType[keyof typeof sizeType];
}
```

If you would like to shorten the code, you could use the `ValueOf` utility type described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49286056/21637817):

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

interface Props {
  size: ValueOf<typeof sizeType>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enums are kind of like classes: they define a type *and* a reified term-level value:

```
enum Foo {
  A,
  B,
  C
}

type F = Foo // See it's also a type, we can type alias it
type G = typeof Foo

const a: Foo = Foo.A // The type is the union of the members: 0 | 1 | 2 
const b: G = {
  A: 0,
  B: 1,
  C: 2
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9nKBvAUFKBBANGqAhHdAYRQF8UUAXATwAdhYoBeWBKAenagGVgGBLSgHIAzlACGAGxGJxUGvSp0GAcWbzlcAGas4FAMZwQIyhIBcu9fDgA6DBy4AVABYMFAsZVdQwIfkahteW8IYAgAI2AAJxELAAYoAB8oAEYkqAAmKBRDY1NwizUWVHQMeMJ8CxSKogsMsgp+EEporXF9BgAJcRFrZFwtBAtrBpyjEyh9C27etmKBod07BqA)

The type defined by the enum is the union of the members, and the type defined by `typeof MyEnum` is the type *of the enum itself*. This is similar to how `class Foo` would define a type `Foo` that represents instances of that class while `typeof Foo` would refer to the type of the class object itself.

So in your code, as far as I can tell from the question, you just want the interface property to be of type `Size`, i.e. one of the members of the enum:

```
interface Props {
    size: Size
}

const whatever: Props = {
    size: Size.S
}
```

Comment: I can't reference the non-exported type `Size`.

Comment: @MichaelLiu gotcha, misunderstood the question. You can use the `keyof typeof Size` approach from wonderflame then, just a word of caution: enums contain both the normal mapping *and* a reverse mapping (you can see this in the compiled output) so it's going to have the numbers 0, 1, 2 in that union as well as the strings S, M, L.