# assigning types to enum members is it possible?

Tags: typescript

is it possible to assign a type like number[] to the enum members for example

const enum Size { Small:number[], Medium, Large };

if not why is it not possible since it is just a collection of constants

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: No, it is not possible and doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Even if this were possible presumably you'd be assigning a *particular* array of numbers to `Small`, not the *type* `number[]`.  What array would you be assigning here?  Assuming it's `[0, 1]`, then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBBYnN) meet your needs? It doesn't use `enum` at all, but `enum` is only really meant for specific use cases and your use case doesn't fit.  If this fully addresses your question I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? Please comment to let me know how to proceed.

Comment: yeah @jcalz thanks for the first approach am just new to typescript but your case worked well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TypeScript `enum`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) are only really meant to support a very particular set of use cases.  The values are always `string` or `number`.  If you want one of the values to be a `number[]`, then you can't use an `enum`.

And you really don't need or want to use an `enum` anyway; you can write the desired object directly and use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to get the behavior you're describing:

```
const Size = {
    Small: [0, 1],
    Medium: 0,
    Large: 1
} as const;

/* const Size: {
    readonly Small: readonly [0, 1];
    readonly Medium: 0;
    readonly Large: 1;
} */
```

Now `Size` is an object known to have keys `Small`, `Medium`, and `Large`, and the values at those keys are known to be exactly the values you initialized it with.  If you want to use `Size` as the name of a type corresponding to those values, you can do it with the technique from
[Is there a `valueof` similar to `keyof` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49285864/2887218) :

```
type Size = (typeof Size)[keyof typeof Size];
// type Size = 0 | 1 | readonly [0, 1]
```

So now you can write the same sort of code you'd write with a true `enum`, where `Size` is both a type name and a value name:

```
const x: Size = Size.Medium; // okay
```

---

There are other differences between this approach and a true `enum`, but you probably don't care about them.  For example, a real `enum` acts as a [`namespace`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#handbook-content) so that `Size.Small` is also the name of a *type* corresponding to `typeof Size.Small`.  If you *do* somehow need this, you can write it out (but it's tedious):

```
namespace Size {
    export type Small = typeof Size.Small;
    export type Medium = typeof Size.Medium;
    export type Large = typeof Size.Large;
}
const y: Size.Medium = Size.Medium; // okay
```

As another example, `enum` types are meant to be *nominal*, so you can't mix and match them even if they have the same values:

```
enum Enum1 { A = 0, B = 1, C = 2 }
enum Enum2 { D = 0, E = 1, F = 2 }
const e: Enum1 = Enum2.D // error, even though it is the same as Enum1.A
```

But do you actually want that to be an error?  Probably not, and if you do, there are ways around that too... but I won't belabor the point since it's even more tedious to do that.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAygSwF4FMYF4YG8BQN-wC2AhgDakBcMA2gAwA0MAjALr14ECyKAJggK6EqDDvgAyxAE4BzFFSY4AvjGIQYoSFADcOAPQAqdeGjxkc7KJiSUxHuFIBPImUpWbdsI5oNmLHQTdbeyduPkFhfwJrIM8nCRlzJh1lfV0cKAcABzREVAwYAAoM7JAAM1NUAEpqAGsUBzKYYpRG3JQ-PV0mrJyzfNoYAB9mIcCPLzpGVhwZjRMADyo2-LaAOlCBQi0YXS6QGuIHGbBiQhQITOJgXrzcAJR5zJBJWGbncnzm1rNVuBJySL4B5PF7dbIwDaCT49b6oda8TaAmDA56vHoweKyaElcprTEoZI4OawBxLH6QwgrckIwTbXYwfaHGY4FBgKEAUTZhCY2BgAEF+owAEL5JiMADC+QATDBFCyuTBOYIZVgYAARQWK0WMABi0tlROMsHMSu5+VNUtWGvpKEkkmejBQADdWU0ABYgfjSN0wBCwBBqKButAQU5oVSKrlMVZ8oA)