# How can I achieve sum type-esque functionality without empty interfaces?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that should only accept arguments that are part of a group that I define. The code explains it better than I can:

```
// Ham.ts
interface Ham {
  a: string
}

// Cheese.ts
interface Cheese {
  b: string
}

// Aux.ts
type Food = Ham | Cheese

const onlyFood = (arg: Food) => {
  console.log("executed onlyFood")
}
```

The data that is modeled by the Food interfaces are not guaranteed to share any common structure.

This approach works fine. However, as I add new Food interfaces (in their own files), I will need to go back into the `Aux.ts` file and update my union type. Is there a way to encode the same functionality without having to modify the `Aux.ts` file on additional interface creation?

My initial idea for a solution was to use an empty interface that I could extend like so

```
// Data.ts
interface Food {}

// Ham.ts
interface Ham extends Food {
  a: string
}

// Cheese.ts
interface Cheese extends Food {
  b: string
}

// Aux.ts
const onlyFood = (arg: Food) => {
  console.log("executed onlyFood")
}
```

but because of TypeScript's structural typing, this approach won't work. Also, Prettier complains about it, which I don't like (even if I can disable it for this line/file).

Any ideas?

Comment: You could use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to add a property to a "food registry" interface and then `Food` is just the values of that interface, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wRAQnW). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yup this works. The extra interface wrapper in each file is a little ugly, but this solution certainly uncouples the files, which is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript's [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) are exactly what you're looking for (e.g., `type Food = Ham | Cheese | ⋯`), but you're not happy about having to enumerate the members of the union in a central location.

TypeScript's [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) type system also means that it's not really feasible to have the language automatically compute a union of all known subtypes of a particular interface, since any type that matches interface structurally will suffice; this is particularly noticeable for [the empty interface `{}` where all non-nullish types are assignable](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces).  If you want a union you'll need to either build it yourself, or "register" its members somehow in another type and have the compiler compute the union from the registry.

---

The only way I can think of that lets the registration occur close to the declaration of the items to be registered (`Ham`, `Cheese`, etc) instead of close to the declaration of the union (`Food`) is to use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), where you have a declaration split across different locations (including different files) and the compiler merges them all into a single logical declaration.

You can't add members to unions directly with declaration merging.  Merging only works in specific scenarios and unions aren't among them.  Instead, you can use [interface merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) to add properties to an interface.  Let's call it `Fridge` (although maybe `FoodRegistry` would be less silly):

```
// Ham.ts
interface Ham {
  a: string
}
interface Fridge {
  ham: Ham
}

// Cheese.ts
interface Cheese {
  b: string
}
interface Fridge {
  cheese: Cheese
}
```

So we've registered both `Ham` and `Cheese` as properties of `Fridge`.  Note that we had to give the properties key names, but they are essentially dummy names that we don't care about.  They need to be distinct from each other for merging to work, but other than that they could be anything.  Then in the central location we have

```
// Aux.ts
interface Fridge { } // merge individual foods
type Food = Fridge[keyof Fridge]
```

(You don't technically need `Fridge` to be declared here if it's in use elsewhere, but this will help prevent errors in the case that you haven't registered any `Food` elements yet.)

The type `type Food = Fridge[keyof Fridge]` uses [the `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) and an [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get the union of all property types of `Fridge`.  (See [Is there a `valueof` similar to `keyof` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49285864/2887218) ).

So if you have only registered `Ham` and `Cheese` then when you inspect `Food` you'll see it as `// type Food = Ham | Cheese`.  If you register another food in `Fridge` it will be added as well.

And so it behaves as expected:

```
const onlyFood = (arg: Food) => {
  if ("a" in arg) {
    arg.a.toUpperCase(); // okay
  } else {
    arg.b.toLowerCase(); // okay, well, until you register more Food
  }
}
```

---

Note that all the usual caveats of scoping across files apply here.  Code in a [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) scope will behave differently from code in a global scope.  If your different files are in different modules then you will need to import/export types and perform [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation). (i.e., with `declare module`) And if you are trying to interact merge into something in the global namespace from within a module then you'll need [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) (i.e., with `declare global`).  So be careful.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAkEMFsDoBcDOAoAlgO3gUwE4DNIBjLCGUAb2VFEgC5RF4cMBzZAXzU1wONADFmAExYlK1ABYx6UaB2TIQoAMISsWRFgQoM2fERKr1milVAAjeo2bo2nXTwMDho09UJqNWeka-zFYACCAK4AHtpcerwkgqgiYqDsoErQuK4YQqgAbnHBkAA2oHgA9sVCiKAYoGo4WMjwAJ4ADjGlQqAAvM5xogDaANZYDcV43fEAugDcAaCNLQJtnaTQoAA+Kp6aCoTF6Iygu-kN-ItdABSQOCz0J2UAlJ0AfG6Vo2cARJDvleg0Vw-iah-FiwSAIYoAVSaLRwykgmjOd0myTAxX6kAaZiSWHyJkB1EuIPM4IAMsUAO64OEIpEog7ozHUTjsIA)